# How to break/exit from a each() function in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code:

```
$(xml).find("strengths").each(function() {
   //Code
   //How can i escape from this block based on a condition.
});
```

How can i escape from the "each" code block based on a condition?

#### Update:

What if we have something like this:

```
$(xml).find("strengths").each(function() {
   $(this).each(function() {
       //I want to break out from both each loops at the same time.
   });
});
```

Is it possible to break out from both "each" functions from the inner "each" function?

**# 19.03.2013**

**If you want to continue instead of break out**

```
return true;
```

Comment: Leads right to the docs: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+for+each+break, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Not a duplicate. The linked question is about `$.each()`, but this one is about `$().each`, they are two different things.

Comment: This is the second link on google for that search.

Answer (score 1081, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) you can simply `return false;` to break:

```
$(xml).find("strengths").each(function() {

    if (iWantToBreak)
        return false;
});
```

Comment: simple 'return' is not working for me. this is why i googled it and found this post. 'return false' works. i am running osx lion with chrome.

Comment: "simple return" actually returns. It will return control from the `each` and everything else around it and after it until it exit's `each()`'s parent control - such as a function() which is using each. This is the correct answer, and the other approach will not work.

Comment: "We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration."

Comment: Notice that this will not KILL the main function, the loop can break, but when you use this  jQuery each to check for required fields before continue, it will continue no matter the break. for that you should use a var kill variable set in the loop, and read outside of it to return if kill==1

Answer (score 136):

You can use `return false;`

```
+----------------------------------------+
| JavaScript              | PHP          |
+-------------------------+--------------+
|                         |              |
| return false;           | break;       |
|                         |              |
| return true; or return; | continue;    |
+-------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I mean to say return false; in javascript is same as break in PHP and return true; or return; is same as continue

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe it is jQuery not javascript

Comment: so Codler what is the difference between return false; in javascript and return false; in jQuery

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe `return false` in javascript is meaning returning boolean type same in PHP. But in `jquery.each()` it will be interpreted by jQuery as stop the looping.

Comment: Returning `false` to jQuery's `.each()` is not the same as `break` in PHP.  You have the right idea, but this is not really accurate.  Plus, this question had a correct answer over 3 years ago.

Comment: You are mixing your concepts here, can't tell if you meant to write "JQuery" where you have "JavaScript"

Answer (score 110):

Return false from the anonymous function:

```
$(xml).find("strengths").each(function() {
  // Code
  // To escape from this block based on a condition:
  if (something) return false;
});
```

From the documentation of the [each method](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> Returning 'false' from within the each
>   function completely stops the loop
>   through all of the elements (this is
>   like using a 'break' with a normal
>   loop). Returning 'true' from within
>   the loop skips to the next iteration
>   (this is like using a 'continue' with
>   a normal loop).

Answer (score 28):

```
if (condition){ // where condition evaluates to true 
    return false
}
```

see  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquerys-each-loop) asked 3 days ago.