# jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a poll with a couple a questions. Here is html code

```
<form id="pool">
 <div class="questions>
  <input type="radio" name="sex">Male
  <input type="radio" name="sex">Female
 </div>

 <div class="questions>
  <input type="radio" name="hair">Brown
  <input type="radio" name="hair">Blonde
 </div>

 .... a lot of qestions div's
</form>
```

What to do so after the form is submitted to be sure that there is a checked radio button in all div`s ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if every radio group has had an option selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796870/determine-if-every-radio-group-has-had-an-option-selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how many groups you have you can just do:

```
if($('#pool input:radio:checked').length < numGroups){
    // At least one group isn't checked
}
```

Otherwise you need to count the number of groups first. I can't think of any way to do this better then:

```
var rgroups = [];
$('#pool input:radio').each(function(index, el){
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < rgroups.length; i++)
            if(rgroups[i] == $(el).attr('name'))
                return true;
        rgroups.push($(el).attr('name'));
    }
);
rgroups = rgroups.length;

if($('#pool input:radio:checked').length < rgroups)
    alert('You must fill in all the fields.');
else
    alert('Thanks!');
```

Answer (score 0):

set default values or create handler for submit button and check if some values was checked. If no radio button is checked, show error message and do not submit form ( return false)

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, but this is the idea:

```
 if($('#pool').children().length == $('pool
 div').find('#pool input:radio:selected').length) { 
 //do stuff 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jquery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)

from my experience this plugin is very efficient