# Targeting $(this) within nested for each loops in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out, when iterating through some list items, how to target each "$(this)" equivalent within nested foreach loops. Here is an example of my problem:

```
$('li').each(function(){
        // I believe $(this) would target each li item...
    $(this).children("li").each(function(){
        // ... but how can I target each of these li items? Doesn't $(this) target the original loop?
    });
});
```

Comment: You want to target li children's ?

Comment: You want to iterate over `<li>`s that are inside `<li>`s?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children("li").each(function(){
        $this; // parent li
        this; // child li
    });
});
```

Comment: @mmmoustache - np glad i could help

Answer (score 34):

Don't use `this`! Use function parameters!

```
$('li').each(function(i, li){
    $(li).children("li").each(function(ii, li2){
        $(li)...
        $(li2)...
    });
});
```

This is more in keeping with the native JavaScript iterators.

...though an `<li>` can't be the direct child of another `<li>`

Comment: Why are you using `this`, then? `$(this).cildren('li')` as opposed to `li.children('li')`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: 'twas a copy/paste omission. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: thanks for this, squint. I never quite got function parameters until your example!

Comment: This answer should be part of JQuery/SO lore! I didn't even know about the parameters.

Answer (score 12):

Look at the basic "prototypes" of jQuery functions (or methods, if you will):

```
$[jQobject].[func]([callback]);
```

The callback is the function that will be invoked *in the context of the jQ object*. The context being `this`, obviously. Put simply that means that:

```
$('#foo').click(function(){});
   /\                 /\
   || Is the context  ||
   =====================
```

The same applies to your case, regardless of the loops being nested or not:

```
$('ul').each(function()
{
    //this is ul
    var that = this;//you'll often see code like this
    $('li', this).each(function()
    {
        //this is li
        //that is parent ul
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation - the documentation is a bit daunting at times but you helped me out!

Comment: This answer is very educational as well.

Answer (score 3):

> but how can I target each of these li items? Doesn't $(this) target the original loop?

Nope.

`this` comes from the function you're *directly* in.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, `this` refers to each of the child `<li>` items. Try it out.

Most (if not all) DOM-interacting jQuery callbacks set `this` to to the DOM element that you're working with.

You could also write:

```
$('li').children("li").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
});
```