# jQuery(this) target isn't finding element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come this works:

```
jQuery(this).closest("li").find("p").text();
```

But when I have it inside a function, it doesn't work:

```
jQuery.each(words, function(i, v) {
    jQuery(this).closest("li").find("p").text();
});
```

Do I need to pass `this` through the function?

Full Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.js-trigger-editb').bind("mouseup", function() {

        // find the p tag that contains the content and split it
        var words = jQuery(this).closest("li").find("p").text().split(" ");

        // wrap words in p tag into span tags
        jQuery.each(words, function(i, v) {
            jQuery(this).closest("li").find("p").append(jQuery("<span>").text(v));
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: OP include html to see that problem :) what is words? `this = v` for this :)

Comment: may be use full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346206/targeting-this-within-nested-for-each-loops-in-jquery

Comment: need the html as well

Comment: Like you said, the value of `this` inside the function is the problem.

Comment: Why not just cache `jQuery(this).closest("li").find("p")` before your loop and then append to the cached var in the loop?

Comment: @techfoobar Can you please demonstrate how to pass `this` through the function?

Comment: is this finding paragraph tags inside a `<li> and appending `<span>` with the tag contents inside? I feel like there might be an easier way to do this. Post the HTML and say what the goal is and you;ll get a better answer

Comment: @Pete Please post an answer outlining this approach. Not sure if I understand how you mean to *cache*...

Comment: @HenrikPetterson - Please see the answer I posted for a way to pass along `this`.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kwav6Le0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to suggest to save the link to the found "p" element not to search it each time.

```
    var p = jQuery(this).closest("li").find("p");
    var words = p.text().split(" ");

    jQuery.each(words, function(i, v) {
        p.append(jQuery("<span>").text(v));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you have mentioned in the question, the value of `this` inside the function is the problem. Inside the callback for `.each()`, the value of `this` is the current item in the array being iterated.

Something like this should work:

```
var elem = this; // here, 'this' is the element. Store it.

jQuery.each(words, function(i, v) {

    // use the stored element handle from 'elem'
    jQuery(elem).closest("li").find("p").append(jQuery("<span>").text(v));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery(this)` is a reference to the DOM element of invocation. So it is different element when you call it inside `jQuery('.js-trigger-editb').bind("mouseup", function() {});` and `jQuery.each(words, function(i, v) {});`.

Try to save it outside the `.each`.

Try:

```
var $this= jQuery(this);
jQuery.each(words, function(i, v) {
    $this.closest("li").find("p").append(jQuery("<span>").text(v));
});
```