# how to identify 'this' object inside nested loop in jquery?

Tags: jquery, loops

When I create loop inside a loop and want to access this element inside the second loop, I referenced to this link([Targeting $(this) within nested for each loops in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346206/targeting-this-within-nested-for-each-loops-in-jquery)).  I use

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Where $this references first loop and $(this) references second. But I need one more inside the second loop and need to access another "this" object of third loop. I need to have something like this

```
  $('.section1').each(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
          $this.find('div[class = "text_question"]').each(function(){
                   $(this).find('label').each(function() {
                            //I want to access the element of this loop (each label object's text)
                });
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `$thisInner = $(this)`? Also why not `$this.find('.text_question label').each()`?

Answer (score 0):

To make it cleaner, you can define parameters for the callbacks:

```
$('.section1').each( function(index, sectionItem) {
    sectionItem.find('div[class = "text_question"]').each( function(index, questionItem) {
        questionItem.find('label').each( function(index, labelItem) {
            // use labelItem here
        });
    });
});
```

You can also find more info here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Also, as Justinas pointed out, you can get the `label` elements with one selector:

```
$('.section1 .text_question label').each( function(index, labelItem) {
    // use labelItem here
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `$(this)` to a variable of any name. So in your 2nd loops you can add `var this2 = $(this)`, or any name you prefer. You can access it by calling the variable directly like `this2.find(...`