# jquery disable submit button unless all radio button group checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Trying to disable a form submit button unless a selection has been made from a number of radio button groups. Have got this far, cant see why not working, button stays disabled:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#button').attr('disabled', true);

                var disable = true;
                $('input:radio').click(function () {
                    $('input:radio').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                            disable = false;
                        else
                            disable = true;
                    });
            });
            $('#button').prop('disabled', disable == true ? true : false);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Side note: This `$('#button').prop('disabled', disable == true ? true : false);` should be just `$('#button').prop('disabled', disable);`

Comment: You only check the state *inside a click event*, but you only change the prop *once on-load*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796870/determine-if-every-radio-group-has-had-an-option-selected

Comment: adeneo's answer should solve the issue but the reason why your code is not working is because you're looking for `click` event instead of `change`. Another issue is in `each()`, you're not stopping at the first checked radio button. So if you've 5 radio buttons and the 3rd one is checked, in 3rd iteration `disable` becomes `false` but the loop continues and in 4th and 5th iterations, it becomes true again :) so you should stop at the moment you see that one of the check boxes is checked by using `break`

Comment: Also your `$('#button').prop('disabled',disable)` should be within the change handler

Comment: @FrankMiller.. i think my solution is incorrect. Can you explain that different radio groups thing once ? wat exactly are you expecting ?

Comment: Hi, was just about to reply, have been trying your solution - my mark up is like this http://jsfiddle.net/ngz33jj0/1/

Comment: Hopefully.. This should work [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngz33jj0/4/) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change the property inside the handler, and the right handler for a radio button would be `onchange`

```
$(function () {
    var button = $('#button').prop('disabled', true);
    var radios = $('input[type="radio"]');
    var arr    = $.map(radios, function(el) { 
                      return el.name; 
                 });

    var groups = $.grep(arr, function(v, k){
                     return $.inArray(v ,arr) === k;
                 }).length;

    radios.on('change', function () {
        button.prop('disabled', radios.filter(':checked').length < groups);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3fkguy9/2/)

Comment: What if there's more than one group of radio buttons to check? This would seem to enable the button if any radio button group had one item checked.

Comment: @FrankMiller - you're welcome, and no, it's not that straight forward, one has to count the number of groups based on unique names, or at least something similar to that