# how to exit outside the jQuery .each loop

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to break/exit from a each() function in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799284/how-to-break-exit-from-a-each-function-in-jquery)

I want to exit the jQuery `.each` loop on some condition, How can I do it. Will `exit;` code work?

```
var r = true; 
$('.hour').each(function() {
   var $hours =  $(this).val();
   if ($hours == "") {
     alert(" Active Time is required"); 
     r = false; 
     //exit;         
   }    
}); 
return r;
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use [`return false`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$(".hour").each(function() {
    if (want_to_break) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `break;` to break out of a conventional loop, whereas with this jQuery `each` function I suggest you `return;` or `return false;`.

Comment: return; or return true; will not stop iterating. Only return false; will work

Answer (score 1):

```
.each(function() {
    if (iWantToBreak)
        return false;
});
```

Repost of the following:

[How to break/exit from a each() function in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799284/how-to-break-exit-from-a-each-function-in-jquery)