# Exit from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw many places similar question but couldn't fix it.

Here's my function:

```
function validate_form(){
     $('#form_data input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            value = $(this).val().trim();
            if(value != '' && value != null && value != 0 ){
                   return true;
            }
     });
     return false;      
}
```

Its not exiting on `return true;`. I have also tried `e.preventDefault()` but no use.

Comment: It should be `return false`.

Comment: @DipeshParmar using break gives me error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to break/exit from a each() function in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799284/how-to-break-exit-from-a-each-function-in-jquery)

Comment: @DipeshParmar It's the jQuery's `.each()` method. It's not a built-in loop structure so `break` won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Break out of Jquery's Each Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquerys-each-loop)

Comment: @Juhana yes i realized that later...sorry

Comment: Exactly what should the function do? Is the form considered valid if there's at least one field filled in? Or must all fields be filled in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` will return from the function it is in. In your code, that is the anonymous function you pass to `each`. See the [documentation for each](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> You can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning `false`.

You are returning `true`, not `false` so you aren't stopping the loop. Change `true` to `false` on line 5 of the function.

Comment: But if you return false, at the end you wouldn't know why the `.each()` ended.

Comment: Set a variable in the scope of `validate_form` and chance it as well as returning false then.

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate_form(){
     $texts=$('#form_data input[type="text"]'); //cache the object
     var len = $texts.length;
     var validItems=0;
     $texts.each(function(){
            value = $(this).val().trim();
            if(value === ''){ // value of a text input cannot be null
                              // or zero unless you've changed in with JS
                   return false;
            }
            validItems++;
     });
     return len===validItems;      
}
```

The function doesn't exactly show what item is invalid, just returns false if any of the items is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You have to let the `.each()` finish before you return from the main function body. You can keep a counter of valid entries you have come across and let the return value depend on that:

```
function validate_form()
{
    var items = $('#form_data input[type="text"]'),
    count = items.length,
    valid = 0;

    items.each(function() {
        value = $(this).val().trim();
        if (value != '' && value != null && value != 0 ) {
            ++valid;
        }
    });

    return valid !== count;
}
```

Btw, I've changed the return value to `false` if there's at least one invalid entry; assuming you're using this as `onsubmit="return validate_form()"`.