# Getting flexbox to flow like bootstrap columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a three column setup with gutters that has equal heights. I'm currently trying to do this with flexbox but the issue I'm having is that if a row ends up having two columns, the `justify-content: space-between;` makes a gap in the middle instead of flowing left to right like bootstrap columns would do. I thought this would be done with `align-content: flex-start;` but I'm either using it wrong or it doesn't work the way I'm trying to use it.
Is there a way to have flexbox use the space between for the gutters but keep the left to right flow? Here is a link to show the issue I'm having and how I want it to look.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWvqdL

Also, is there a way to use flexbox with the padding and column width % setup of bootstrap then have a child element inside the column that is 100% height?

Comment: My answer here may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34930349/3597276

Comment: By "phantom elements" you mean kind of like empty cells in a table?

Comment: Bit late, but an addition of 'flex-grow:1' on the column together with `justify-content: space-between`  doest the trick

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I decided to do it. I'm using the standard bootstrap set up, with the padding on columns and negative margin on the parent, but setting `display: flex;` to the parent and the column with `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the parent. This way, I can use the boostrap column percent width and have equal height from flex.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMExMJ

Comment: First, only post one answer please. Second, yes, that works good too ... and if I see right, the difference between mine and yours is you use padding/margin to achieve the gutter and I use nth-child/margin .. so it is like tea, some wants lemon, some milk :)

Comment: And if you limit the width (resize your codepen demo), your gutter collapse, mine doesn't ... here is my [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/s6xqqbgb/1/) if you want to check

Comment: Ya, I only posted a second answer because it was completely different than when I thought it wouldn't work and I would have to resort to javascript. I guess I should have edited my answer instead.
It was your example that gave me the idea of how I ended up doing it. The reason I went with my method instead of yours is because I wanted it dynamic enough to put whatever width column I want and be able to change that column width on responsive without have to do a new nth-child. So, my final code is essentially bootstrap but with equal heights from flexbox.

Comment: I updated my version for multi columns. ... Also, you didn't ask for a mixed column solution, you asked for a 3 column, which all answers attempt to solve. Adding your own based on some else's, telling it can do mixed columns, IMHO, goes beyond your initial question. Most fair would be to choose the answer that best solve your initial question and ask a new with new requirements (as this already got answers based on your initial request)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that does what you want.

It shows both a 2 and 3 column layout, with just 2 extra CSS rules

```css
.container2,
.container3 {
  max-width: 840px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.container3 .column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: calc(33.33% - 8px);
  background: #000;
}
.container3 .column:nth-child(3n+2),
.container3 .column:nth-child(3n+3) {
  margin-left: 12px;
}
.column-content {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.container2 .column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
    width: calc(50% - 6px);
  background: #000;
}
.container2 .column:nth-child(2n+2) {
  margin-left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container3">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Update based on comments for mixed columns*

```css
    .container {
      max-width: 840px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .flex {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      margin-left: -12px;
    }
    .column {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      margin-left: 12px;
      background: #000;
    }
    .column-content {
      padding: 20px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .col2 {
        width: calc(50% - 12px);
    }
    .col3 {
        width: calc(33.333% - 12px);
    }        
    .col4 {
        width: calc(25% - 12px);
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
  
    <div class="column col3">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column col3">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column col3">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column col2">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column col2">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column col2">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column col4">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column col4">
      <div class="column-content">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like this might work.
I will give it a try when I get back into work tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: I figured out how I want to do this. If you're curious, check out my newest answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way is by removing `justify-content` and managing the gutters with `margin` then using the `:nth-child(n)` selector to selectively remove the margin so the elements fit. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyVEJZ

Comment: Too bad this method doesn't have a nice way to have the columns equal 100% all the way across like bootstrap does. I ever have a little gap at the end of the third one, or it wraps down a line at smaller window sizes. You can see the gap here. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWvVZB

Comment: Here's a workaround - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bExgGW?editors=1100 basically the problem is that without flex, you will never get 3 columns to take up exact 33.3333% increments and not wrap.

Comment: (pay special attention to my usage of `.flex:after` to fill the "gap" where there should be a 3rd cell in the bottom row. You might have to add two of these if there will ever only be 1 cell in a row).

Answer (score 1):

One method to solve the problem would be to include a "phantom" div as the last child with `visibility: hidden`.

I've copied the first flex item from your code and pasted it as the last item in the container. I've added a `hidden` class to it.

```
<div class="column hidden">
  <div class="column-content">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWvrRX)

For other options, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34930349/3597276

---

The reason `align-content: flex-start` doesn't work as you expect is because the `align-*` properties work along the cross axis. In this case, as your flex container is `flex-direction: row`, the cross axis is vertical. So `align-content`, `align-items` and `align-self` would move your flex items up/down, not left right.

For an illustration of main axis / cross axis, and more details about the `align-*` properties, see here: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)