# Flexbox - Single item in row

Tags: html, css, media-queries, flexbox

I have the following Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxZRJP?editors=1100

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navigation">
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #003f8f">
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #548122">
    <a href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #f4a628">
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #d21527">
    <a href="#">4</a>
  </li>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  height: 190px;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.navigation-item a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

If you resize the viewport to around 1200px the fourth item will wrap and grow on its own single row.

To prevent having the fourth item singled out, I could write a `@media-query` with a fixed viewport size and change the `flex-basis` or give the items a `min-width`.

**So my Question is:**
Is there any more flexible way, to have no item singled out?

**EDIT:**
I want the items to wrap and I want the items to fill all the available space. So removing `flex-grow` or `flex-wrap` is not really an option.

Comment: Do you mean same `width` but they should shrink?

Comment: @NenadVracar Yeah, either the fourth item should shrink to the width of the other three items or the third item should wrap together with the fourth item. If this makes sense to you....

Comment: Just remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` like this https://jsfiddle.net/m7dfvw24/4/

Answer (score 2):

You could get a lot of inspiration for this thread: [Flex-box: Align last row to grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid)

In your case, you could do a lot of small thing to achieve what you want in a simpler way.

1/ Add `box-sizing: border-box`, so the padding is included in the defined width. See for more explanations http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

2/ Use `calc()` to remove the margin from the width, so every item will fit on the line.

```css
/* New box-sizing, so the padding and the border are included in element sizing */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: flex;
  
  /* Make the 4 elements to fit in a single line */
  flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 30px);
  height: 190px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation-item a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #003f8f">
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #548122">
    <a href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #f4a628">
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #d21527">
    <a href="#">4</a>
  </li>
</nav>
```

3/ If you want to 4th element to be on a separate line, you could change the flex-basis

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: flex;
   
  /* We make that only 3 elements fit in a line */
  flex: 1 1 calc(100% / 3 - 30px);
  height: 190px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation-item a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;

  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #003f8f">
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #548122">
    <a href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #f4a628">
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation-item" style="background: #d21527">
    <a href="#">4</a>
  </li>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is not really helping me. But thanks anyway.  By the way: calc() in flex-basis is not working in ie10. So if you still have to support <= ie10, you can't use that.

Comment: I like to share the simplest demonstration. If you want to use `calc()` with IE10, set it for the `width` and use `flex-basis: auto`. I updated my answer, since your question is more clear now ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any more flexible way, to have no item singled out / have all items with the same width all the time?

Yes, remove `flex-grow: 1` from your flex shorthand.

So instead of this:

```
.navigation-item {  flex: 1 1 20%; }
```

Try this:

```
.navigation-item {  flex: 0 1 20%; }
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQMZeE?editors=1100)

The [`flex-grow: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) rule is telling flex items to consume all available space in the container. When they share a row, the available space is distributed evenly among them. But when the fourth item wraps to the second row *by itself*, it takes all the space.

Also, if you don't want the items to shrink, you would adjust `flex-shrink`:

```
.navigation-item {  flex: 0 0 20%; }
```

***Except*** you're using a percentage width, so the flex items will shrink for that reason.

Comment: Thats a good clarification, but I want the items to fill all the available space...

Comment: In your question, you say you want to *have all items with the same width all the time*. Please clarify, and I will revise my answer.

Comment: So maybe my answer here is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34928565/3597276