# How can a flex item keep the same dimensions when it is forced to a new row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container with 3 children. On each child `max-width` and `min-width` is set, so that when the screen size changes, I can have them look decent without too much effort.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.child{
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 450px;
  min-width: 350px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: blue;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    test content
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    test content
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    test content
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the screen becomes so small that 1 of the children is forced to a new row, it doesn't have the same size as the other 2 children above it:
[image]

Is there anyway to force the child on the new row to have the same width as its siblings?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ekdkbvk/

Comment: `max-width: 350px;` and `min-width: 350px;` ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. In your image above with the red arrow, the boxes in the first row are near their minimum allowed width (`min-width: 350px`), and the box on the second row is near its maximum allowed width (`max-width: 450px`). The layout is doing exactly what you ask. What exactly do you want boxes to do on wrap? Be a fixed width?

Comment: @Michael_B: I want to have a way to have that third box's width mirror the width of the first and second boxes. I do not want the boxes to have a fixed width because by setting a `min-width` and `max-width`, The boxes are always guaranteed to be within those dimensions (which are the ranges that make the contents within readable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an invisible flex item in the last slot will work for you.

Add this code to your CSS:

```
.container::after {
    content: "";
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 450px;
    min-width: 350px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jqaae2u1/)

---

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add one rule, which caused a slight overflow to the right of the pseudo-element.

```
.container::after {
    content: "";
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 450px;
    min-width: 350px;
    margin-right: 10px;        /* to match the other flex items */
}
```

[**REVISED DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jqaae2u1/1/)

---

More details in this related post: *[Properly sizing and aligning the flex item(s) on the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34928565/3597276)*

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling I had to fake an extra element to achieve this. I used a media query to add it so that when the screen has a lot of width, you don't get that empty slot on the right.

Comment: Quick update: The element on the lower left (see your fiddle) will always be slightly larger than expected. Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: Here's a more accurate fiddle demonstrating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/w03ckz7c/1/

Comment: @F21, yes I see that `flex-basis: 0` solves the problem in your revised code. In my answer (which uses the code posted in your question), the solution is to add `margin-right: 10px` to the pseudo-element. Something I forgot to do in my first run. Sorry about that. Answer revised.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `flex-grow: 1;` from `.child` will solve your issue.

```
.child{
  max-width: 450px;
  min-width: 350px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: blue;
  height: 400px;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ekdkbvk/1/)**

**Or other solution:**

Use `flex-basis: 100%;` to `.child`.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ekdkbvk/2/)**

Comment: If I remove `flex-grow: 1`, the children no longer expand to their max width of `450px` even when there's space. If I add `flex-basis: 100%`, the children won't attempt to shrink down to fit before being wrapped to a new row.