# pseudo-element acting like a grid item in CSS grid

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-grid

I'm creating a form that has required fields. To mark these as required, I'm putting an asterisk (*) as a `::before` element and floating it right so it is by the top right hand corner of the field.

The issue I'm having is a few of these fields are positioned with CSS Grids and when I add a `::before` element to the grid, it is treated as another grid item and pushes everything over to a new grid row.

Why is CSS grids treating the `::before` element as another grid item? How would I make the asterisk be positioned like the input elements?

Here's the basic HTML/CSS:

```css
html {
  width: 75%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

input {
  width: 100%
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: .33fr .33fr .33fr;
}

li.required::before {
  content: '*';
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="required">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="grid required">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
  </li>
  <li class="required">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zbqucvt9/

Comment: A pseudo-element generates the same kind of box that an actual element does. As far as CSS layout is concerned, a pseudo-element box and an actual element box are two of a kind. You'll find pseudo-element boxes behaving identically to actual element boxes in pretty much any other situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pseudo-elements are considered child elements in a grid container ([just like in a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40686928/3597276)). Therefore, they take on the characteristics of grid items.

You can always remove grid items from the document flow with absolute positioning. Then use CSS offset properties (`left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`) to move them around.

Here's a basic example:

```css
html {
  width: 75%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

input {
  width: 100%
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li.required::after {
  content: '*';
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="required">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="grid required">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
  </li>
  <li class="required">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
</ul>
```