# CSS GRID avoid ::before and ::after in grid

Tags: css, css-grid

When I am working with CSS Grid some how grid also take before and after as gird elements. Is there any way to work about this?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: "::before element";
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "::after element";
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display:none` ?

Comment: Why are the ::before and ::after there in the first place? What purpose do they fulfill? Knowing this would make it easier to help you solve the problem.

Comment: It is dynamically created by woocommerce.

Comment: What do you want to happen? If you meant to use them as headers or footers, i.e. spanning the entire width of the grid, use `grid-column: 1 / -1` on them.

Comment: just remove your content from after and before then these boxes are gone? not sure what else you're asking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pseudo-element acting like a grid item in CSS grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599317/pseudo-element-acting-like-a-grid-item-in-css-grid)

Answer (score 5):

try This

```
.wrapper::after, .wrapper::before{ display:none !important;}
```

Comment: also try  !important

Answer (score 0):

You can change their order to make them always at the end and add some properties to also hide them. Like that you are sure they will not bother you.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: "::before element";
  order:9999;
  visibility:hidden;
  display:none;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "::after element";
  order:9999;
  visibility:hidden;
  display:none;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could also add `opacity: 0` just to make triple sure that it is gone ;)