# Span background color across viewport width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to build a responsive navigation bar with **CSS Grid** layout that spans across the viewport width, but the inner items should be centred and aligned with other container elements on the page.

The result that I want is displayed in the code below, however, I don't feel that this is an elegant solution as I used 2 separate `<div>` elements stacked on top of each other.

*One `<div>` is for having the items centred and the second `<div>` is to cover the `background-color` across the viewport width.*

---

Is there a better way of doing this using the **CSS Grid** layout?

**[EDIT] I am looking for a way to make the technique reusable on multiple elements.**

---

***Please expand the code snippet to full page so the layout appears correctly***

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(4, minmax(min-content, 150px)) 1fr;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / span 4;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-underlay {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / span 7;
  height: 50px;
}

.content {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / span 4;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <div class="nav">this box should stay aligned with the content box</div>
  <div class="nav-underlay"></div>
  <div class="content">Content box</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the background area you're looking to expand is for decorative purposes only (i.e., you're not using that area to convey content), then you can use CSS pseudo-elements instead of an actual HTML element.

Pseudo-elements become grid items when applied to a grid container ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45599317/3597276)).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(4, minmax(min-content, 150px)) 1fr;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / span 4;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.container::before {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  content: "";
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50px;
}

.container::after {
  grid-area: 1 / -1 / 2 / -2;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50px;
  content: "";
}

.content {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / span 4;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <div class="nav">this box should stay aligned with the content box</div>
  <div class="content">Content box</div>
</body>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y1uaw2q5/)

Comment: This is a nice and clean solution and it answers my original question. If I wanted to add another element(eg. a banner) that would need to span across the viewport width in a similar fashion like the navigation bar, I could only apply the `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements once? Is there a way to make this technique reusable on multiple elements?

Comment: Hi @Michael_B, any idea for this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119276/extra-space-when-center-elements-using-flexbox ?

Comment: @Lenny86, it would be tricky at this point, since pseudo-elements are considered children of their container. So, like you said, this can only be done once in a grid container. Ideally, you would be able to apply the pseudo-elements to grid items, and have the pseudo-elements respect the primary container's lines. That capability (`display: subgrid`) is in the works, but not available yet. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929369/3597276