# Why the navbar's height so big?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

[image]

Why is this navbar's height more than 1 row? I just want it to be 1 row.

Note: This is only a small part of the code, can anyone tell me the reason why the height is so big, so I can modify according to the suggestion? I don't want to change the html structure too much.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2 p-0 bg-primary">a</div>
    <div class="col bg-faded py-3">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the default alignment which is stretch. It works fine when both element are in the same row but when there is a wrap you will have 2 lines with the same height and each element will be stretched inside making you first element to have half the height of the container:

To avoid this, you can change the alignment on small screen considering `align-content-*-*` (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#align-content)

We make the alignment to be `flex-start` that we change to `stretch` at the `md` breakpoint:

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 align-content-start align-content-md-stretch">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2 p-0 bg-primary">a</div>
    <div class="col bg-faded py-3">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is another question with more details to better understand what is happening: [extra space when centering elements using flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53119276/8620333)

Answer (score 0):

height is so big because you add `h-100` on your code, remove `h-100` shows block size of your element

Comment: h-100 is add to its parent, can you explain more about it?

Comment: h-100 is bootstrap class to give element 100% height

Comment: I know h-100 is a bs class, why adding it to navbar's parent will impact the navbar. I added the h-100 here because i want the container to take full height.

Comment: because when you give 100% height to container, each element of your container got 100%

Comment: like in jsfiddle if you give `bg-primary` to c element it also have 100% height

Comment: Apparently, bg-primary does not do anything related to height. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i know, anyway you got your final answer, i am happy for that

Answer (score 0):

Remove `h-100` from `class="row"`

**EXPLAIN!**

when you set `h-100` to `row` mean `height:100%` -

`100%`

> Set the height of an element to 100% of the height of the parent
>   element(in your case `container-fluid`) and not `auto` according the contains inside the element

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2 p-0 bg-primary">a</div>
    <div class="col bg-faded py-3">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more explain

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, can you help to answer why the h-100 works fine in below example: https://www.codeply.com/go/Rgq96HykJ2/sidebar-that-changes-to-navbar