# before:: pseudo-element span all columns in grid

Tags: html, css

I have a two column grid.

```css
main {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 6.4rem;
}

h3::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  height: 1px;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<main>
<h3>Heading blah</h3>
<p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
<h3>Heading blah</h3>
<p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
<h3>Heading blah</h3>
<p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
</main>
```

```
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 6.4rem;
}
```

With headings in the left column and body text in the right column.

Is it possible to have a `border-top` on my `H3` headings (that display in the left column), that span both columns? Possibly using the before:: pseudo-element? So a horizontal line appears above the headings and goes across both columns. Like trying to insert a `<hr>` element before every `H3` that spans both columns.

I've got the following:

```
h3::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

But the border-top stretches outside the width of the containing element (`main`) and touches the right hand side of the browser window. `Position: relative` doesn't seem to work.

UPDATE

I've tried this, but the black line only stretches across one column.

```
h3::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

UPDATE 2

I guess I need the CSS grid to treat the before:: pseudo-element as an actual element, in order for it to span more than one column? Is that possible? According to this 5 year old post pseudo-elements are treated as an element in grid. [pseudo-element acting like a grid item in CSS grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599317/pseudo-element-acting-like-a-grid-item-in-css-grid) But that isn't the case for me.

Comment: Please update with some sample HTML so we may best assist you here

Comment: I made a wild probably incorrect guess and made a snippet, please update with the proper HTML here

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is because your pseudo-element is a child of `<h3>`, therefore it is constrained to the dimensions of its parent, which only spans a single column.

Comment: But in this post the pseudo-element is treated as an element in the grid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599317/pseudo-element-acting-like-a-grid-item-in-css-grid

Comment: Can you change the layout to wrap the columns? Are there ever two paragraphs (or other markup) at that same level?  Why not just give them both top borders? A few uncertainties here

Comment: I need the horizontal line to go across the gutter. There is a lot of content, but it always just <h3> and <p>

Comment: I suppose a work around is to have no grid-column-gap. But add padding right to <h3> and padding left to <p> to create a 'gap' and then add border top to both <h3> and <p>

Comment: Is there something inherently problematic about just using a `<hr>`? ([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d4mn152r/))

Comment: I've got a lot of content and was hoping not to have to add elements such as <hr> to the html. But to come up with a CSS work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows, with explanatory comments in the CSS:

```css
/* using custom properties to style aspects of the elements in order
   to position them appropriately and consistently: */
:root {
  --grid-padding-block-start: 0.5em;
  --grid-separator-height: 0.2rem;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 6.4rem;
  /* added spacing between adjacent rows, using the custom property
     that also defines the height/block-size of the separator: */
  grid-row-gap: var(--grid-separator-height);
  /* I chose to use position relative on the <main> element, rather
     than the <h3>, in order to have the sizing and position relative
     to the grid-container, rather than the grid-item: */
  position: relative;
}

main > * {
  /* a padding isn't necessary; but if a padding is used (and only
     padding-block-start needs to have this property-value) then
     using the custom property allows the "separator" pseudo-
     element to be appropriately placed in the grid-row-gap spacing: */
  padding-block: var(--grid-padding-block-start);
}

h3::before {
  content: '';
  /* the element size on the inline-axis (left-to-right in latin languages),
     100% is relative to the <main> element, not the <h3>, as that's the first
     element ancestor with a non-static position: */
  inline-size: 100%;
  /* sizing the element along the block-axis, and this is why the
     grid-column-gap was also given this size: */
  block-size: var(--grid-separator-height);
  /* adjust to taste: */
  background-color: #000;
  /* to allow the pseudo-element to be sized in relation to the <main>, in terms
     of percentage: */
  position: absolute;
  /* moving the element zero along the x-axis, and 100% of its own block-axis size
     plus the size of the custom property (so that it occupies the grid-row-gap space,
     and multiplying that by -1 to ensure that it moves vertically 'up' into that space
     rather than further 'into' the <h3> element space: */
  translate: 0 calc(-1 * (100% + var(--grid-padding-block-start)));
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h3>Heading One</h3>
  <p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
  <h3>Heading Two</h3>
  <p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
  <h3>Heading Three</h3>
  <p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d4mn152r/2/).

References:

- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
- [CSS Custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [CSS Logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
- [`grid-row-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/row-columns).
- [`grid-row-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/row-gap).
- [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-block-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start).
- [`margin-block-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-end).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-start).
- [`margin-inline-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-end).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
- [`padding-block-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block-start).
- [`padding-block-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block-end).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
- [`padding-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start).
- [`padding-inline-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-end).
- [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
- [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate).

Comment: I've simplified this, so that I can understand it(!) and this is the solution I intend to use. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with some likely fragile CSS but I would suggest wrapping the blocks and setting a border there (set blocks (div?) all to `display: grid`

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 6.4rem;
}

main>p {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

h3::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 3px;
  width: 225%;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  display: inline-block;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0;
  border-top-width: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h3>Heading blah</h3>
  <p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
  <h3>Heading blah</h3>
  <p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
  <h3>Heading blah</h3>
  <p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: With a little tinkering I think that could work. The  width would need to be calc(200% + grid-column-gap); Thank you

Comment: Yea, width I just put on there for the example - still somewhat fragile but seems like an exception workaround when you cannot wrap the groups and style the wrapper

Comment: Why is this "somewhat fragile"?

Comment: @user2991837 ANY time you put CSS directly to an HTML tag (``h3, p, min") I consider fragile unless it is part of some library or some super high level reset code etc.

Answer (score 1):

One line of code can do it using `border-image`

```css
main {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 6.4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
  /* 5px = thickness 
     15px = distance from the top
  */
  border-image: linear-gradient(180deg,#000 5px,#0000 0) fill 0//15px 100vw;
}
```

```html
<main>
<h3>Heading blah</h3>
<p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
<h3>Heading blah</h3>
<p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
<h3>Heading blah</h3>
<p>Velluptiae dolupiet, im ea dolut que expercia sandionsed mo minvelibus modi occati sit autat quis ut fugitias maio. Moluptat.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: I will shortly have an article about this kind of trick and will link it when it's live

Comment: Sorry I think this is relevant: the <main> has a max-width and is centred on the screen – so the 100vw doesn't work. I don't want the line to extend out past the <main> element. I've updated my code. Any work around?

Comment: @user2991837 add overflow:hidden to main

Comment: That's cool! Two lines of code!

Comment: I'm trying to understand this solution, by breaking it down into smaller parts (using the border-image long hand) but can't get it to work. Can you help me? I've updated my opening post

Comment: @user2991837 please don't keep adding more questions inside your question. Use the devtools to get the longhand version, In any browser you can, with a click, extend any shorthand property

Comment: Thank you. That works. Wasn't aware that I could do that. Thank you