# Why does the w3-panel class from W3.CSS break my grid layout?

Tags: css, css-grid, w3.css

Working on a site that uses [W3.CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp), I came across this issue where adding a `w3-panel` class to the grid container messes up the layout of the grid items.

This was a bit surprising, as the [`w3-panel` docs](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_panels.asp) only mention that it adds margins and padding:

> The w3-panel class adds a 16px top and bottom margin and a 16px left and right padding to any HTML element.

Here's a minimal example of a grid without W3.CSS:

```css
#my-grid {
  /* grid settings */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  /* cosmetics */
  column-gap: 10px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

#my-grid div {
  /* cosmetics */
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

And here's what happens if we add the `w3-panel` class from W3.CSS:

```css
#my-grid {
  /* grid settings */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  /* cosmetics */
  column-gap: 10px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

#my-grid div {
  /* cosmetics */
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div id="my-grid" class="w3-panel">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

What is going wrong here? How can we fix this?

[This discussion](https://w3schools.invisionzone.com/topic/56706-w3css-w3-panel-breaks-css-grids/) may be related.

Answer (score 0):

The [W3.CSS source](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css) shows that the `w3-panel` class does a bit more than just add margins and padding.

These are all the CSS rules related to `w3-panel`, extracted from the [W3.CSS source](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css):

```css
w3-panel:after,.w3-panel:before {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.w3-panel {
  padding:0.01em 16px;
  margin-top:16px;
  margin-bottom:16px;
}
```

The `w3-panel:before` turns out to be the culprit here, as it creates a pseudo element that is treated as a grid item, as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45599317). This is confirmed in the snippet below.

```css
#my-grid {
  /* grid settings */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  /* cosmetics */
  column-gap: 10px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

#my-grid div {
  /* cosmetics */
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}

#my-grid:before {
  /* reproduce the issue */
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div id="my-grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

One way to work around this is issue (other than not using w3.css) is *not* to apply the `w3-panel` class directly to the grid container itself, but, instead, wrap the grid container in another element. This is probably more robust in general. See snippet below:

```css
#my-grid {
  /* grid settings */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  /* cosmetics */
  column-gap: 10px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

#my-grid div {
  /* cosmetics */
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="w3-panel">
  <div id="my-grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a good indicator to stop using such messy framework. It's using a clearfix so I suppose it still uses Float.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree, but, unfortunately, it's not my choice.

Comment: well, you are combining grid with an old framework so you have the choice. You have to choose one way not combine both. Either the old framework or the modern ways

Comment: @TemaniAfif The rest of the codebase uses w3.css. Prevailing guideline is *not* to add custom styling, unless there is no other way. In this case there *is* a simple way to work around the problem. This Q&A is just intended to inform other people that may run into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t see why mix w3.css with hand coded grid having w3.css your own grid internal support.

One approach to achieve something like your first example could be, for example :

```
​<div class="w3-row" style="background-color:lightsalmon">
  <div class="w3-col s3 w3-margin-right w3-purple">1</div>
  <div class="w3-col s3 w3-margin-right w3-purple">2</div>
  <div class="w3-col s3 w3-margin-right w3-purple">3</div>
</div>
```

For more information take a look at [w3.css Fluid Grid documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_grid.asp)

Saludos,

```html
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
<div class="w3-row" style="background-color:lightsalmon">
      <div class="w3-col s3 w3-margin-right w3-purple">1</div>
      <div class="w3-col s3 w3-margin-right w3-purple">2</div>
      <div class="w3-col s3 w3-margin-right w3-purple">3</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is beside the point. The example provided is just a minimal reproducible example. W3.CSS "fluid grid" has many limitations that do not match with our requirements.