# aligning the first and last flex items to the left and right respectively

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

Given the following [HTML](http://www.bootply.com/etREVvzyqJ)

```
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
    <div class="banner row images">            
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.3tonus.com/2014/images/gallery/tower/thumbs/finalfull.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.3tonus.com/2014/images/gallery/tower/thumbs/finalfull.jpg" />
      </div>          
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.3tonus.com/2014/images/gallery/tower/thumbs/finalfull.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.3tonus.com/2014/images/gallery/tower/thumbs/finalfull.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.3tonus.com/2014/images/gallery/tower/thumbs/finalfull.jpg" />
      </div>
  </div>
```

and css

```
div.banner.row.images {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div.banner.row.images div {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

How do I get the fifth image to align right, so that all the space taken up is in the middle of the flex box.

I have tried `space-between`, but that creates a left margin on the far left image, and a right border on the far right image.

I want the first image left aligned, the last image right aligned, and space in between, or just let the images grow to fill the space.

[Booply Here](http://www.bootply.com/etREVvzyqJ)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35719124/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element `.row` from bootstrap has some pseudoelements added in default bootstrap css which will crash your flex for this elements. All you have to do is add:

```
div.banner.row.images::before,
div.banner.row.images::after {
    content:none;
}
```

and then remove `flex: 1 1 auto` for `div.banner.row.images div` and add `justify-content: space-between` to`div.banner.row.images`.
Images will be aligned to left and right without default container padding. If you want to have this padding just remove class `row` for `.banner` element.

Comment: thanks, been struggling with it for hours, didn't occur to me that bootstrap 'row' was the culprit...!