# Inconsistent flex-grow in last row with flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flex-grow

please look at my very simple example of flex layout:

There is

- container with

  - flex box turned on (display: flex)
  - wrapping (flex-wrap: wrap)
- some items in it that have

  - flex-grow is set to 1 = **all items will scale equally**
  - flex-shrink is 0 = any items will not be scale down
  - flex-basis = **all items have same base width**

Despite all the rulesets, items in last row have different width? How it this possible when the flex-grow says that all items will be scaled equally?

Quote from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp:

> The flex-grow property specifies **how much the item will grow relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container**.

That's cool, but my items in last row grow little bit more that others. Any ideas?

```css
flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
item {
  flex: 1 0 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<flex>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
</flex>
```

Comment: How about changing `1 0 4rem` to `1 0 auto`?

Comment: Well I need to have the items with same width. If I set that to auto it varies of content inside.

Comment: What about `0 0 4rem`? The question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Closer, almost there, items are equal. But I want to fill the empty space on the right. http://i.imgur.com/MUJlU6i.png

Comment: This is not possible with flexbox...that's not the way the line box model works.

Comment: I agree with Paulie_D, but if you're ok with a fixed number of items in each row and ok to use percentage width, it's probably doable.

Comment: Oh...and [**Flex-grow:1 does not mean what you think it means**](https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/)

Comment: well container will have variable width and variable number of items, only basis in px will be specified, but I found a solution for this, check http://codepen.io/pravdomil/pen/RaLpMm?editors=1100 this is perfect, but I want to get rid of the <balancer> hack

Comment: @Paulie_D I understand now, it distributes the rest of space at the end of the row, thanks for resourse

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what you want when the browser window is rather wide, you will still be seeing the whitespace on the right.

Comment: well I works for normal sizes of browser window, but you are right if your browser is too wide, there will be whitespace on blank, this is small workaround for now

Comment: the conclusion is: not possible in CSS

Comment: Instead of the <balancer> hack, you can try a pseudo-element: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34928565/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flex [grow](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-flex-grow-factor) and [shrink](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-shrink) factors are basically used to [Resolve Flexible Lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths). But that happens independently for each flex line (row or column).

> To resolve the flexible lengths of the items **within a flex line**: [...]
>
> - If using the flex grow factor
>
>   Find the ratio of the item’s flex grow factor to the sum of the flex grow factors of all unfrozen items **on the line**. Set the
>     item’s target main size to its flex base size plus a fraction of the
>     remaining free space proportional to the ratio.
> - If using the flex shrink factor
>
>   For every unfrozen item **on the line**, multiply its flex shrink factor by its inner flex base size, and note this as its scaled flex
>     shrink factor. Find the ratio of the item’s scaled flex shrink factor
>     to the sum of the scaled flex shrink factors of all unfrozen items on
>     the line. Set the item’s target main size to its flex base size minus
>     a fraction of the absolute value of the remaining free space
>     proportional to the ratio.

The CSS Working Group is aware of this problem and [plans to introduce some way to fix it in Flexbox Level 2](https://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css-flexbox-2)

> Solve the “items on the last line get way too big when you're flexing”
>   problem. More generally, “make items have a consistent flexed size,
>   regardless of how much extra space is on each line”.
>
> - Possible solution - fill out the last line with “phantom copies” of the last item, flex with them in, then remove them.
> - Possible solution - calculate minimum values of 1fr and alignment free space across the entire flexbox (instead of per-line) and use
>     that.

Comment: @pravdomil Do you mean about Flexbox Level 2? It hasn't been written yet.

Comment: I meant using the flex grow/shorink factor

Comment: @pravdomil Ah, then you are already using them, `flex: 1 0 4rem` sets the flex grow factor to 1 and the flex shrink factor to 0.

Comment: Sorry, I got it now.

Answer (score 3):

it is easy by add css just like:

```
.flexlast::after{ //here use after add a element
    content: "  ";
    flex: 100;    //100 just big enough, maybe 50 is ok too.
}
```

```css
flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
item {
  flex: 1 0 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
flex::after{
    content: "  ";
    flex: 100;     
}
```

```html
<flex>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
</flex>
```

Comment: I want to like this but it goes wrong when the last row has the exact right number of items, the `::after` item squeezes in and ruins alignment.