# Inconsistent margin between flex items on last row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using `flex`. There seems to be an unexpected margin difference between two `div` elements  - the third row has a different margin between the divs than the first two rows:

[image]

How do I amend the code so that the third row's margin is the same as the first two rows?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container:after {
  flex: 1;
  content: '';
}

.container form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.container .comment {
  flex: 1;
}

.square {
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(100% / 9);
  margin: 0.7vw 0 0.7% 1vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" style="margin: 0.7vw 0 0.7% 1vw;">
    <input class="comment" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ydyoqmx/

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your pseudo-element is consuming all available space on the last row.

[image]

Yes, this is done to neutralize the effect of `justify-content: space-between` on two flex items, which causes them to appear on opposite ends...

[image]

... but it also kills the proportional spacing that `space-between` provides when the items fill the row.

Until the flex specification is revised with specific last-row alignment properties, you could implement a hack that solves this problem:

> Add invisible flex items after the last real item.

In the example below, I've added seven phantom items to your code.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/*
.container:after {
  flex: 1;
  content: '';
}
*/

.invisible { visibility: hidden; }

.container form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.container .comment {
  flex: 1;
}

.square {
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(100% / 9);
  margin: 0.7vw 0 0.7% 1vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" style="margin: 0.7vw 0 0.7% 1vw;">
    <input class="comment" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  
  <div class="square invisible"></div>
  <div class="square invisible"></div>
  <div class="square invisible"></div>
  <div class="square invisible"></div>
  <div class="square invisible"></div>
  <div class="square invisible"></div>
  <div class="square invisible"></div>
</div>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4ydyoqmx/8/)

More information:

- [flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276)
- [Properly sizing and aligning the flex item(s) on the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34928565/3597276)

---

### Sidenote

There's a good chance you'll encounter some trouble with this rule:

```
.square { margin: 0.7vw 0 0.7% 1vw; }
```

The [flexbox specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#item-margins) advises against using percentage margin and padding in a flex container.

> **Authors should avoid using percentages in paddings or margins on flex items entirely, as they will get different behavior in different browsers.**

Here's some more:

> [**4.2. Flex Item Margins and Paddings**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#item-margins)
>
> Percentage margins and paddings on flex items can be resolved against either:
>
> - their own axis (left/right percentages resolve against width, top/bottom resolve against height), or,
> - the inline axis (left/right/top/bottom percentages all resolve against width)
>
> **A User Agent must choose one of these two behaviors.**
>
> Note: This variance sucks, but it accurately captures the current state of the world (no consensus among implementations, and no consensus within the CSSWG). It is the CSSWG’s intention that browsers will converge on one of the behaviors, at which time the spec will be amended.

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant answer _(it's quite amazing actually!)_. While I hadn't thought of adding invisible divs to make the last row mirror the first two rows, I don't believe it would be the most convenient solution as I am later planning on using my code in a `foreach` loop and I feel it would be a little complicated having to use a PHP function to count the number of divs and depending on how many there are, substitute hidden ones. I've upvoted your answer as I feel it'll be brilliant for other users who encounter the same problem :)

Comment: Hi Michael, its been over a year now and I was wondering if the only option is still to implement a 'hack' or whether the specification has been revised?

Comment: Hi. Nothing has yet changed with flex. The last-row alignment problem still exists. However, with the advent of CSS Grid, there's now a clean, simple and easy solution: https://jsfiddle.net/4ydyoqmx/12/

Comment: More details: [Targeting flex items on the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176419/3597276)

Comment: Grid demo explained: [Equal width flex items even after they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44154580/3597276)

Comment: Oh, that seems cool - I'll have a look at it! Is it possible to set the max number of items per row?

Comment: Yes, you can set a maximum number of items per row. In the revised demo below, I've set the max to 5. Their width is an equal distribution of the space on the row. https://jsfiddle.net/4ydyoqmx/13/

Answer (score 2):

There is a few different ways of doing this, depending on how you want the "squares" to respond:

`flex-grow`:

```
.square {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% / 9);
    margin: 0.7vw 0 0.7% 1vw;
    background: red;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ydyoqmx/2/

`inline-block`:

```
.square {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% / 9);
    margin: 0.7vw 0 0.7% 1vw;
    background: red;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ydyoqmx/4/

Third Option:

Removed `content: ''` from `.container:after` because that was causing problems

Comment: I suppose the best option so far is using `flex-grow`. I was trying to avoid your second suggestion as I wanted the last div to end where the submit button ends _(if you get what I mean)_

Comment: Just remove `content: ''` and see how you like that

Comment: It floats one of the div's over to the right which isn't particularly what I wanted

Comment: Your option, I personally like the `flex` option the best.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `justify-content: space-between` setting on `.container` which does this (in conjunction with `flex-wrap: wrap;`):
It evently distributes the elements in those lines that are filled, but in the last line that would not look good, so it leaves the predefined / default margin between those elements. (That's similar to a justified text paragraph)

One possibility to avoid this is to simply erase `justify-content: space-between`, thereby setting it to the default`left`alignment (but they won't be distributed across the whole width anymore):

https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejaob7/

Comment: I was trying to avoid this as I wanted the last div to end where the submit button ends _(if you get what I mean)_

Comment: I really don't see a reason why this is downvoted (explanation?). But it seems a big downvoter has been riding along all these answers...

Comment: I have upvoted your answer as I believe it contains  valuable information and doesn't deserve a downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

It is doing like that because you're justifying content using space between. So on the screen it can not accommodate 7th div so it puts only 6 div on screen and puts equal space between 6 div elements.But in the last line there has only 2 div's so that means your 3rd line is not fully filled with div elements. That's why it is not putting space as it did on upper line's div's .

If you put 4 more div's then you'll get exact effect as it has on upper line's .

Answer (score -2):

This problem could be solved by adding this piece code to your css..

```
*{margin:0px;
padding:0px}
```

Hope it works..

Comment: @SangameshDavey it didn't fix the problem, [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/7a0xyhhk/). Make sure to resize so there are six items in the first two rows.