# Flex grid with odd numbers of items and fixed margin between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Ok this is giving me quite an headache...

this is my code/example

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXpjYa

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.imageContainer {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: deeppink;
  margin:15px;
}

.imageContainer:empty {
    height: 0;
    border: none;
};
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="imageContainer">a</div>
    <div class="imageContainer">a</div>
    <div class="imageContainer">a</div>
    <div class="imageContainer">a</div>
    <div class="imageContainer"></div> 
    <div class="imageContainer"></div>
</div>
```

the problem is that I want to achieve/fix two things:

- the far left and far right column should be touching the edge of the viewport
- the fixed gap should be 30px and only the pink boxes stretch responsively
- notice the last item (5) is slightly wider than the others...why??

please help! thanks!

Comment: [Equal width flex items even after they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44154580/3597276)

Comment: [Targeting flex items on the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176419/3597276)

Comment: [add-spacing-to-flexbox-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497785/add-vertical-spacing-to-flexbox-items-only-when/46511858#46511858)

Answer (score 1):

You set the margin to be `15px`, on `.imageContainer` this applies to all sides, including the sides between these `imageContainer`s and the viewport. So basically your first ask and your second ask are fighting against each other.

You can set a margin on `.imageContainer` and a negative margin on the parent `.flex` to accomplish both.

The last visible item is longer because the two divs following it are collapsing and not showing, which affects the layout. If you add the css attribute `box-sizing: border-box` to your `.imageContainer` rule, it will fix this issue. You can also assigned a fixed height to `.imageContainer`, or add content to all of the `.imageContainer` divs to prevent this from happening.

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/BrandonKerr/pen/qPpMJg) for the modified code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of margin use `justify-content: space-between` and set `flex: 0 0 30%` instead of `flex: 1 0 30%`. Last item is bigger because there is no border on other two.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.imageContainer {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: deeppink;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.imageContainer:empty {
  height: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="imageContainer">a</div>
  <div class="imageContainer">a</div>
  <div class="imageContainer">a</div>
  <div class="imageContainer">a</div>
  <div class="imageContainer"></div>
  <div class="imageContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach makes it much harder to have a set distance between items.

Comment: @Bricky Not really.

Comment: You would need to set the children elements width to the (width of the parent container, minus (the number of gutters * width of the gutters)) / number of children elements. Otherwise you'll end up with off-set rows as the number of children elements grow.