# CSS: Flex is resizing div on next row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My problem is that whenever I resize the window, the divs should warp to the next row if there is not place with the same size as all the other divs.

View this in "Full Page" and try to resize yourself.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper" style="display: flex; width: 100%; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;">
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block; flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block; flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it should look like:
[image]

Comment: [Equal width flex items even after they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44154580/3597276)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can't have the same size on 2nd row with the given setup.

And reason is when you set `flex: 13px`, it means `flex: 1 1 13px`, hence they will grow, if there is space left, until they reach the `max-width`, and when to little space, they will shrink until reaching the `min-width`.

There is also no possibilities to detect when an item wrap, so to keep the `min/max-width` concept you need to add a few media query's.

*Note, the `!important` used in the CSS is needed to override the inline value of `250px`*

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1c8Lbpvh/)

Stack snippet

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
#wrapper div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  #wrapper div:nth-child(6) {                /*  6th child  */
    max-width: calc(100% / 5) !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 750px) {
  #wrapper div:nth-child(n+5) {              /*  from 5th child  */
    max-width: calc(100% / 4) !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {                  /*  from 4th child  */
  #wrapper div:nth-child(n+4) {
    max-width: 250px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="display: flex; width: 100%; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;">
    <div id="content1" style="display: inline-block; flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content2" style="display: inline-block; flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content3" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content4" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content5" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content6" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `justify-content` from `center` to `flex-start` in `#wrapper` which is by default is `flex-start` and then it align child `divs` to `left` every time when user resize.

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="display: flex; width: 100%; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content:flex-start;">
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block; flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block; flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: inline-block;flex: 13px; text-align: center; background-color: red; border: 3px solid grey; height: 200px; min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px;">
      Hey!
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: OP does not ask for left align, they ask for equal width, which also is shown with the posted image.

Comment: Yeah @LGSon just read that again, OP must have corrected me that this is not what I'm trying. +1 learned something new from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `flex: 13px;` from the `div`. Also, you are using same `id` for all the divs, please remove that. I have used `class` instead.

Below is the solution

```css
          #wrapper {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
          }
          .content {
             text-align: center;
             background-color: red;
             border: 3px solid grey;
             height: 200px;
             min-width: 150px;
             max-width: 250px;
          }
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
          <div class="content">Hey!</div>
          <div class="content">Hey!</div>
          <div class="content">Hey!</div>
          <div class="content">Hey!</div>
          <div class="content">Hey!</div>
          <div class="content">Hey!</div>
          <div class="content">Hey!</div>
          <div class="content">Hey!</div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Now they don't flex anymore, between 150px - 250px width.