# CSS Flex items, equal width with a min-width

Tags: css, flexbox

Given the following list of items:

[image: List items not at same width]

How can I have the remaining items use the width of the of the ones preceding it. I would ideally prefer to not set `flex-basis` to a fixed width so things stay responsive.

The relevant CSS is as follows:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `flex: 1 auto;` for `<li>` elements?

Comment: I changed to `display: grid` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154580/equal-width-flex-items-even-after-they-wrap