# Menu entries equally spread over two lines

Tags: html, css, layout, word-wrap

I have a menu (`ul` tags) whose elements are inline. Right now, the elements wrap when they reach the width of the container:

[image: Right now]

This is what I would like is to force the menu to be on two lines:

[image: Goal]

If extra entries are added, I would like the menu to equally divide on the two lines:

[image: behavior]

I'm ideally looking for a way to do it with css only. I tried using `flexbox` and `writing-direction` without succes. I'm open to a javascript solution but would like to have soft enought solution to allow for different designs in other responsive modes.

Edit:

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Le projet</a></li>
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Les numéros</a></li>
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Obtenir le magazine</a></li>
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Devenir coopérateur</a></li>
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Nous contacter</a></li>
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Proposer un sujet</a></li>
</ul>
```

and CSS (I simplified wit honly the relevant code)

```
.main-menu__entry {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
  margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
  color: black;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154580/equal-width-flex-items-even-after-they-wrap).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? This is definitely a scalable solution, but should be useful for now.

```css
.main-menu__entry {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
  margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
  color: black;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Le projet</a></li>
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Les numéros</a></li>
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Obtenir le magazine</a></li>
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Devenir coopérateur</a></li>
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Nous contacter</a></li>
  <li class="main-menu__entry"><a href="#">Proposer un sujet</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I'm looking for. The menu should be over two lines and the lines should be balanced.

Comment: Can you put your html and css here so that I can get some idea what you want?

Comment: Here it is: I added my HTML and CSS in the question

Comment: I think, simply adding some fix width should be ok. Try adding  width: 150px; to the class. It looks like what you want. Ofcourse , it is not scalable solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution, but it is not scalable indeed.

Comment: Updated the answer as per the above discussion. If this helps, feel free to accept it :)