# Center inline blocks using CSS

Tags: html, css

Please have a look at the example below, than contains a large div which in turn contains a lot of smaller divs inside.
 Each div has a fixed width of `150px` and a display of `inline-block`, so the browser will fit as many as possible in a single line.
 The problem is that whenever there is unoccupied horizontal space in the large div it doesn't get shared by the `margin: auto` property of the children, but rather stays on the left of the large div.

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#parent>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to center the divs while also allowing more than one div per row and having the same alignment on the bottom regardless of how many elements it shows?

Comment: Not using `inline-block` - no. There are other options, CSS-Grid for one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154580/equal-width-flex-items-even-after-they-wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `display: inline-block` basically displays a block element as if it were a word. So if I understood your problem correctly, it should be enough to add this CSS

```
#parent {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This does answer my question, but this messes the margin of the bottom row (I understand that I didn't specify that on the question, and that it's my fault). Is there a way to make it so that the divs on the bottom row are properly aligned?

Comment: @nickzoum Please define "properly aligned"

Comment: @nickzoum it's a bit more complicated then. There is `text-align-last: left` but that just pushes the whole line to the left, don't think that's what you want. Are you able to modify the HTML? Or should it be CSS only?

Comment: @elveti Even if i can modify the html (fairly easy in my case), I would need a different amount of elements depending on the current width of the page.

Comment: I'm accepting and upvoting, not sure why you got the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `text-align:center` to your parent

```
#parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

hope that was your question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#parent>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
</div>
```

Set the parent `text-align` to center.