# My 25% width flex item is taking 100% width after wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having a small problem. I was always using floating to arrange my elements. I am moving to flexbox, I made some examples and everything was good but I am making an example which things are not going well.

I have a container having between 1 to 12 products, 4 for each line. I made a simple example using only four and it is working, but now I am making an example with five elements, the first row looks fine, but the fifth element take 100% of the products container, but I want it to take only 25%, the sixth takes 25% and so on.

That what I see:

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<div class="container-2">
      <div class="item-2">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="item-2 p2-2">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="item-2">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="item-2 pp2">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="item-2 pp2">
        ...
      </div>
</div>
```

And That is my CSS :

```
.container-2 {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  padding: 20px 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item-2 {
  padding: 0 15px;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the items set to `flex: 1 0 25%`.

This breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 0`
- `flex-basis: 25%`

Remove `flex-grow: 1`. It's telling the items to consume free space.

Try this: `flex: 0 0 25%`

For more details and other options, see these posts:

- [Equal width flex items even after they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44154580/3597276)
- [Flexbox: 4 items per row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29546550/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `flex: 0 1 auto`.

Comment: it would be helpful if you would elaborate on why you recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `box-sizing: border-box;` and `flex: 0 1 25%;` for `.item-2`

Answer (score 1):

Make it correct -

```
.item-2 {
      padding: 0 15px;
      flex: 0 0 25%;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you have to properly set up the `box-sizing` attribute:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Without this, in some situations, your 4th element will be falling to the next row