# Maximum number of rows flexbox/grid css

Tags: css, flexbox

My goal is to display 4-8 boxes in a grid of 2-4 rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/vbf0379s/

```
.twit-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5%;
  margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
  position: relative;
}
.twit {
  max-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 1%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex-grow: 1;
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Here's the same thing in grid:

http://jsfiddle.net/03g27end/

The boxes should expand to fill the available space without being very strictly controlled in size. However whenever I try it if the screenspace isn't sufficient for an even number of items the last row's items deforms.

The idea is to achieve what youtube has:

[image]

[image]

If there is only enough room for 3 columns, I would like the last row to not be shown at all. In the flexbox example the items blow up in an ugly way, and in the grid they just dangle there.

Is this possible with just flexbox/or grids or other methods without media queries or do I have to calculate based on screen size?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44154580/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif you're right thanks, I refined my question to be more distinct from that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a combination of `grid-template-rows`, `grid-auto-rows` and `overflow-hidden` you can hide implicitly created rows.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.twit-container {
  background: teal;
  padding: calc(5% - 10px);
}

.twit-container-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.twit {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main class="twit-container">
  <div class="twit-container-inner">


    <article class="twit">
      <div class="twit-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="twit-content">
        <p class="twit-text">
          Sitting in web dev... This class is so awesome!
        </p>
        <p class="twit-text">
          Para 2!
        </p>
        <p class="twit-text">
          Sitting in web dev... This class is so awesome!
        </p>
        <p class="twit-attribution">
          <a href="#">CSMajor2017</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="twit">
      <div class="twit-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="twit-content">
        <p class="twit-text">
          text
        </p>
        <p class="twit-attribution">
          <a href="#">BeaverBeliever</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="twit">
      <div class="twit-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="twit-content">
        <p class="twit-text">
          text
        </p>
        <p class="twit-attribution">
          <a href="#">NewtonRulez</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="twit">
      <div class="twit-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="twit-content">
        <p class="twit-text">
          Huh?
        </p>
        <p class="twit-attribution">
          <a href="#">ConfusedTweeterer</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="twit">
      <div class="twit-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="twit-content">
        <p class="twit-text">
          text
        </p>
        <p class="twit-attribution">
          <a href="#">Setup</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="twit">
      <div class="twit-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="twit-content">
        <p class="twit-text">
          text
        </p>
        <p class="twit-attribution">
          <a href="#">Punchline</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="twit">
      <div class="twit-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="twit-content">
        <p class="twit-text">
          text
        </p>
        <p class="twit-attribution">
          <a href="#">Hess</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="twit">
      <div class="twit-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="twit-content">
        <p class="twit-text">
          text
        </p>
        <p class="twit-attribution">
          <a href="#">TheIRS</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have problems, though, when I try to use the “gap”. It makes the overlapping rows visible stuffed at the bottom inside the grid container.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply set [`flex-shrink`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-shrink/) and [`flex-grow`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/) and [`flex-basis`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-basis/) properties in one line(shortform) using `flex` property like -

```
flex: 1 1 200px; /* flex-grow:1; flex-shrink:1; flex-basis:200px;*/`
```

### Example

```css
.twit-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
  position: relative;
}

.twit {
  flex: 1 1 240px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 1%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<main class="twit-container">
  <article class="twit">
    <div class="twit-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="twit-content">
      <p class="twit-text">
        Sitting in web dev... This class is so awesome!
      </p>
      <p class="twit-text">
        Para 2!
      </p>
      <p class="twit-text">
        Sitting in web dev... This class is so awesome!
      </p>
      <p class="twit-attribution">
        <a href="#">CSMajor2017</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="twit">
    <div class="twit-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="twit-content">
      <p class="twit-text">
        text
      </p>
      <p class="twit-attribution">
        <a href="#">BeaverBeliever</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="twit">
    <div class="twit-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="twit-content">
      <p class="twit-text">
        text
      </p>
      <p class="twit-attribution">
        <a href="#">NewtonRulez</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="twit">
    <div class="twit-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="twit-content">
      <p class="twit-text">
        Huh?
      </p>
      <p class="twit-attribution">
        <a href="#">ConfusedTweeterer</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="twit">
    <div class="twit-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="twit-content">
      <p class="twit-text">
        text
      </p>
      <p class="twit-attribution">
        <a href="#">Setup</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="twit">
    <div class="twit-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="twit-content">
      <p class="twit-text">
        text
      </p>
      <p class="twit-attribution">
        <a href="#">Punchline</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="twit">
    <div class="twit-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="twit-content">
      <p class="twit-text">
        text
      </p>
      <p class="twit-attribution">
        <a href="#">Hess</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="twit">
    <div class="twit-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="twit-content">
      <p class="twit-text">
        text
      </p>
      <p class="twit-attribution">
        <a href="#">TheIRS</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
<button type="button" id="create-twit-button"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i></button>
```

Comment: Yes but this stretches the bottom row instead of showing fewer items.

Comment: you can alter the `flex-basis` to avoid it

Comment: yes but then that would be identical to my example and doesn't cut off the last line.

Comment: OK may be you can edit your question or set bounty on it to get great answer