# Maintain even spacing for fixed width elements in Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container like this with a maximum of three set-width blocks inside of it.
[image]

By setting *justify-content: space-between* on the parent container; it equally spaces the child blocks when there are three present. However, when there are only two blocks, space-between causes it to look like this:

[image]

When there are two blocks, I would like instead for the child elements to both align to the left side of the parent, maintaining the same spacing that would be present if there were three elements (see the image below). I know of a few ways to address this including using vanilla CSS, but I'd rather not specify hard-coded margins unless it's a last resort. I considered using *justify-content: start;* and then applying selective/calculated margins based on the width of the child elements/parent.

Am I missing something? Is there a simple way to achieve this layout with flexbox?
[image]

Comment: a CSS grid job: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44158826/8620333

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif! Grid-Gap does look like the perfect solution... the only issue is that I have to support IE11...