# Setting flex container to content width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I thought this was simple but I can't get is right. I have a `.notes-container`. The width should be set by the content of the `.first-line`. And the the `.second-line` should take the same width. The width of `.notes-container` should not be set but adjust to `.first-line`. The problem is to let the `.second-line` adjust to the `.first-line` width.

```css
.notes-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first-line {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.second-line {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="notes-container">

  <div class="first-line">
    <div>content 1</div>
    <div>content 2</div>
    <div>content 3</div>
    <div>content 4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="second-line">
    <div>content 5</div>
    <div>content 6</div>
    <div>content 7</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154580/equal-width-flex-items-even-after-they-wrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `.notes-container`, switch from `display: flex` to `display: inline-flex`.

The former takes up all available space in the row.

The latter adjusts to the width of the content.

```css
.notes-container {
  display: inline-flex; /* adjusted */
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first-line {
  display: flex;
}

.second-line {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="notes-container">

  <div class="first-line">
    <div>content 1</div>
    <div>content 2</div>
    <div>content 3</div>
    <div>content 4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="second-line">
    <div>content 5</div>
    <div>content 6</div>
    <div>content 7</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: display: inline-flex; /* adjusted */ SOLVED MY PROBLEM! I knew it should be simple. Thanks!