# Can I set wrapped flexbox columns to equal width and stretch their width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I'm making responsive gallery and would like to avoid using media queries while it can be done with flexbox. I set flex-grow to 1, so the columns fill available space and added min/max-width, so they stay in a nice size. The problem is - when columns start to wrap I have:

- 3 regular columns on first line.
- 2 bigger columns on the second line.

I would like the second line columns to have the same width as the first one.

jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xu92m43e/1/

**Current result:**
[image: current result]

**Expected result**
[image: expected result]

html:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 5px black;
  > * {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: purple;
    min-width: 175px;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
    &:after {
      display: block;
      content: '';
      padding-bottom: 75%;
    }
  }
}
```

*Solutions without flexbox may be good too, as long as it can wrap the columns.*

Comment: Flexbox can't do that natively. It's a common request.

Comment: One method for solving this problem is with hidden flex items: https://jsfiddle.net/xu92m43e/3/

Comment: @Michael_B Smells like a dupe to me. :)

Comment: @Michael_B hey that's a good idea! Wish i could put a few :after elements on the container to get same result.

Comment: @DariuszSikorski, pseudo-elements can work, as well.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/34928565/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B almost... for 1920px view I'd need like 10 of these.

Comment: What's the problem with media queries?

Comment: this cannot be solved only with flex! @Paulie_D for ur case, it needs only one another empty div in gallery and all is broken.