# Empty li using for style only; valid in HTML5?

Tags: css, html, flexbox, html-lists, flex-grow

I want to make an `ul` that breakes into a few lines with `flex-wrap`. So far so good but, if there are multiple lines, I want all lines exept the last one to take the rest of the width of the line. So I used `flex-grow: 1;` on the `li`'s. However as the last line shouldn't have `flex-grow` I just put an empty `li` after all the others an gave it `flex-grow: 9999;`, so that they don't take the whole width. (See Example for better understanding)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

li:last-of-type {
  flex-grow: 9999;
}

/* Unimportant */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}

li {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: blue;
}

li:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>abcdefghijklm</li>
  <li>abcdefghijklm</li>
  <li>abcdefghijklm</li>
  <li>abcdefghijklm</li>
  <li>abcdefghijklm</li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Now, I have the question: Does HTML5 allow to just put an **`li`** at the end only for **styling reasons**?

(If there exists another CSS function for using flex-grow on these lines, I would be very happy, but I don't think so.)

---

*I already searched for this, but I didn't realy know how to search, so I couldn't find something.*

Comment: So long as the elements are placed within a permitted parent (`<li>` can only appear wrapped within a `<ul>` or `<ol>` for example) then html has nothing to say about whether you use empty elements for styling purposes. Semantically it feels wrong to me, but it’s opinion based, so it only matters whether you’re happy to have empty elements as hooks for presentational styling.

Comment: but why 9999 and not simply 1 like the other?

Comment: 9999 is simply to prevent the li's in the last row to grow. Normal li's with flex-grow: 1; will only grow very little. (https://joren.co/flex-grow-9999-hack/)

Comment: Okay, thank you David Thomas. Think the answer below is perfect: Using the pseudo elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly valid, but there may be a better way.

Instead off adding an extra DOM element to your code, you can use a CSS pseudo-element.

Pseudo-elements on flex containers are treated like flex items ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/23#CSS)). The `::before` element is the first item, and the `::after` is the last.

Try this instead:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

ul::after {
  content: "";
  flex-grow: 9999;
}

/* Unimportant */
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}

li {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: aqua;
}

li:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>abcdefghijklm</li>
  <li>abcdefghijklm</li>
  <li>abcdefghijklm</li>
  <li>abcdefghijklm</li>
  <li>abcdefghijklm</li>
</ul>
```

See these posts for more information and other options:

- [Properly sizing and aligning the flex item(s) on the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34928565/3597276)
- [Targeting flex items on the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176419/3597276)

Comment: I didn't think of that one, thank you, think I will use this!

Answer (score 1):

Michael_B's answer shows how the issue can be avoided. But addressing the question directly, this is about something that the HTML5 spec calls [Palpable content](https://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#palpable-content). It says:

> As a general rule, elements whose content model allows any flow content or phrasing content should have at least one node in its contents that is palpable content and that does not have the hidden attribute specified.
>
> This requirement is not a hard requirement, however, as there are many cases where an element can be empty legitimately, for example when it is used as a placeholder which will later be filled in by a script, or when the element is part of a template and would on most pages be filled in but on some pages is not relevant.

So `<li>` elements *should* not be empty, but it is not invalid in itself if they are. However, to have the element just for styling is not an approved reason for it to be empty.