# Stop function if condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the Array `map()` Method to check each element in an Array and if the condition in the if clausel is true i call another function.

```
$.map(data['icd'], function (field, i) {
   if(field.nummer == search){
      Diagnose.single(field.id);
   };
});
```

Now my problem is that i want to stop the `map` method if a element fullfills the if condition. Because i noticed that when i have for example 6 elements that fullfill the condition the function `Diagnose.single(field.id);` is called 6 times instead of once!

I tried:

```
$.map(data['icd'], function (field, i) {
   if(field.nummer == search){
      Diagnose.single(field.id);
      return true;
   };
});
```

But this didnt worked! What can i do instead? Thanks

Comment: have you tried break;

Comment: `this didnt worked` ... please elaborate.

Comment: that defeats the purpose of `map`, use $.each function instead http://stackoverflow.com/q/1799284/1117720

Comment: Just read the specification of map. And do a for loop by yourself. Is it *that* difficult to write a function with a for loop ????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use simple for-loop with break statement:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data['icd'].length; i++) {
   if (data['icd'][i].nummer == search){
      Diagnose.single(data['icd'][i].id);
      break;
   };    
}
```

`map` is used for different tasks.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not need IE8 support, you can use `Array.prototype.some`

```
data['icd'].some(function (field, i) {
   if(field.nummer == search){
      Diagnose.single(field.id);
      return true;
   };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Return false and replace .map with .each

```
$.each(data['icd'], function (field, i) {
   if(field.nummer == search){
      Diagnose.single(field.id);
      // Need to return false, return true will go for a success and still continue.
      return false;
   };
});
```

Comment: I don't think this works... in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) for map, it states: The function can return: 1) the translated value, which will be mapped to the resulting array. 2) null or undefined, to remove the item. 3) an array of values, which will be flattened into the full array.

Comment: Sorry, you also have to replace .map with .each, I already edited my initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case you want to use the [jQuery each function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). You can then `return false` to break out of the loop

```
$.each(data['icd'], function (field, i) {
   if(field.nummer == search){
      Diagnose.single(field.id);
      return false;
   };
});
```

or even better, use a simple for-loop as @disq shared.