# How to synchronize $.each(); function with called function in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I kept one function in $.each() function and sending an array of elements to that function by using $.each() function. But the $.each() function doesn't care about the function and itself running.

Please solve my problem

This is the code

```js
$.each(addrArray, function(i, item) {
    alert(addrArray[i].ActualAddress);
    getLatLang(addrArray[i].ActualAddress, addrArray[i].BusinessEntityID);
   });
```

Comment: If you mean how to stop iteration, `return false`.

Comment: how about return false?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this one 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799284/how-to-break-exit-from-a-each-function-in-jquery

Comment: no no, the $.each() function doesn't take care about the function which is called in itself.

Comment: [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) says what..?

Comment: [*"We can break the `$.each()` loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return `false`. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration."*](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: it is not error.. for each and every element the function has to some output but it is not giving...The $.each() function won't wait for that function call...

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing `getLatLang` is asynchronous, in that case...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: In that they are saying put setTimeout() function. But i have put that function also. Not getting

Comment: any solution is there for my question?

Comment: what is the` getLang` function doing? is it from some library?

Comment: The getLatLang() function will take address from the array and pass it to the google maps and get latitude, longitude coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have Ajax call written in `getLatLang()` function; i will suggest to make that Ajax call synchronous like follows:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'your url for getting lat-long',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {your address},
        async: false,
        success: function() {}
      });
```

Here `async: false` will do the job. Your program execution will remain in this function till the time you get back your lat-long from server. Once returned from this function; your `.each` loop will get incremented.

Answer (score 0):

```
each(function() {
if (something) 
return false;
});
```

For Documentation : [Link](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Sir, the thing is not about break the loop. How to synchronize the loop with call function in it