# "return false" is not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following code works fine if I don't use `return false;` in `imageload` function. But if use `return false;` it's not working. I even tried break. It didn't help.

```
    function fileshow(sel){
       var file=sel.files[0];

        var imagetype=file.type;

        var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
        if(!((imagetype==match[0]) || (imagetype==match[1]) || (imagetype==match[2]))){

          return false;
        }
        else{

            var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = imageload;
          reader.readAsDataURL(sel.files[0]); 

        }
      }
    function imageload(e){
      $(".fileshow").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==''){
          $(this).siblings(".inner_mainphoto").find("img").attr("src", e.target.result);
          return false;                 
        }
      });       
    }
```

### Update

I want to break out of the each function if `$(this).val()` is empty.

Comment: You just forget to explain your expected behaviour. Posting non working code doesn't help to get what is your expected behaviour...

Comment: A. Wolff bro I have updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break/exit from a each() function in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799284/how-to-break-exit-from-a-each-function-in-jquery)

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss bro this is not a duplicate question. there they told to use return false in the answer. I am already using return false but it is not working

Comment: What that says is you have not provided enough information OR that your `e.target.result` is the challenge.  what does `console.dir(e);` before that conditional show for that value?

Comment: Is it even entering the `if` condition?

Comment: @Akshay if I dont put return false there, it enters the if condition and changes the src attribute. but if I put return false the main function (imageload) itself not working