# jQuery function doesn't exit after return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code part:

```
$.each(myArray, function(index, val) {
        
  if (val == "Test" ) {
     
     console.log("FOUND")
     return
  
  }
    
});
    
console.log("DEBUG")
```

I get both logs:
"FOUND" and "DEBUG"

But I would like to exit the function directly after the value was found.
I guess that my "return" only exit the loop, but not the whole function.

Is there any solution that I can exit the loop and exit the function in one line?

Comment: `return` ends the anonymous function you pass as callback to `$.each()`. It doesn't end `$.each()`

Comment: `return` always used to get out from the current scope function execution and this is how it is working in your code.

Comment: "*Is there any solution that I can exit the loop and exit the function in one line?*" why even use jQuery for this? Use a regular loop or a JS iteration method like `.find()` or `.contains()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799284/how-to-break-exit-from-a-each-function-in-jquery