# jquery each leave early

Tags: jquery, each

I have a jQuery for-each loop on an array and wonder if it is possible to leave the loop early.

```
$(lines).each(function(i){  
    // some code  
    if(condition){  
        // I need something like break;  
    }  
});
```

`break;` actually doesn't work, for a reason.

If I'd write a for-loop it would look like that (but I don't want that):

```
for(i=0; i < lines.length; i++){  
    // some code  
    if(condition){  
        break; // leave the loop 
    }  
};
```

Thanks in advance
-Martin

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Break out of Jquery's Each Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquerys-each-loop)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each):

> If you wish to break the each() loop at a particular iteration you can do so by making your function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop, it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

Answer (score 4):

**Return boolean false;**
    (SEE http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each , fourth paragraph)

```
$(lines).each(function(i){  
    // some code  
    if(condition){  
        // I need something like break;  
        return false;
    }  
});
```