# Breaking a jQuery loop when value matches

Tags: jquery

I am comparing my current date and time with a list of date and times I have. At the very end of the code I am comparing whether getDates is bigger than output. I want to stop looping when it is true and use the matched value (to stop I am using return false). How I can do it please? I made a note saying "MATCHED VALUE GOES HERE" which I am thinking that is the place where I need to insert something.

```
    // Get current date, format it
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var hour = d.getHours();
var minute = d.getMinutes();

var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + ' ' +
((''+hour).length<2 ? '0' :'') + hour + ':' +
((''+minute).length<2 ? '0' :'') + minute
alert(output)

// Get all dates and time found in the table on this page
$('td:first-child').each(function() {
    var getDates = $(this).text();


// Check if dates in table expired. If expired skip and display upcoming one
// if getDates is bigger than output then stop looping and use it

    if ( getDates > output) {
        alert('true')
        return false;
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: new Date(MATCHED VALUE GOES HERE)});
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery each leave early](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857186/jquery-each-leave-early)

Answer (score 0):

You were returning before the `countdown` was set.

Try

```
if ( getDates > output) {
    alert('true')
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: new Date(getDates)});
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the function return false.

```
$('td:first-child').each(function() {
    var getDates = $(this).text();


// Check if dates in table expired. If expired skip and display upcoming one
// if getDates is bigger than output then stop looping and use it

    if ( getDates > output) {
        alert('true')
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: new Date(MATCHED VALUE GOES HERE)});
        return false;
    }
}
```

From the docs:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function > return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it > will skip immediately to the next iteration.