# How to exit from $.each function when condition met

Tags: jquery

How can I exit from `$.each` loop when a condition is met? I don't want to iterate the collection further.

```
$(vehicles).each(function() {
    if (this["@id"] === vehicleId[0]) {
      vehicle = this;
    }
});
```

I tried with `break;` & `return;` statement but it looks the execution doesn't not stop at that point. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the conditional is ever met? maybe try this.attr('id') instead?

Comment: Don't use `@` because it has been deprecated. Also, why not simply use `vehicle = $('#' + vehicleId[0])`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Break out of Jquery's Each Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquerys-each-loop)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Returning false is the equivalent of breaking out of a $.each loop. So in your example:

```
   if (this["@id"] === vehicleId[0]) { vehicle = this; return false; }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to explicitly

```
return false;
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

Since `.each()` iterates over a wrapped set and executes the given function on each element, `break` won't affect the actual iteration. However, you can achieve what you're after without iteration by simply calling

```
vehicle = $('#' + vehicleId[0], $(vehicles));
```

or (as suggested by Kobi in a comment)

```
vehicle = $(vehicle).filter('#' + vehicleId[0]);
```

Comment: That'd be `$(vehicles).filter('#id')`, iirc, you cannot filter a collection that way.

Comment: @Kobi, Actually, both work. Your version is arguably better (at least it's a lot clearer what is actually being done) but mine should work too. If `vehicleId[0]` has a value of, say, "id", my line of code will look for `'#id'` in the context of `$(vehicles)`, which is exactly what your line does too. =)