# JQuery - Abort each function

Tags: jquery, each

how can I abort the jquery `each` function?

```
$.each(big_test_object, function(i)
{
   // some code

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of jQuery each Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquery-each-loop)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

from the [jquery each documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

```
$.each(big_test_object, function(i)
{

   if(i == 'yourvalue') {
          return false;
   }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

you should return false in your callback

cheers