# How do I break out of an $.each in jquery?

Tags: jquery

**How to I break out of the following jquery each method when a condition is met;**

```
var rainbow = {'first' : 'red', 'second' : 'orange', 'third' : 'yellow'};

$.each(rainbow, function (key, color) {

  if (color == 'red') {

    //do something and then break out of the each method
    alert("i'm read, now break.");

  }

});
```

Comment: I think it's a "return".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Break out of Jquery's Each Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquerys-each-loop)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var rainbow = {'first' : 'red', 'second' : 'orange', 'third' : 'yellow'};

$.each(rainbow, function (key, color) {

  if (color == 'red') {

    //do something and then break out of the each method
    alert("i'm read, now break.");

    return false;

  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

As explicitly written on jQuery's page for `$.each` :

> We can break the $.each() loop at a
>   particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false.
>   Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it
>   will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Please google the terms you search before posting here ! It's a pity that jQuery has one of the best documentations ever if you do not bother to read about it !

Comment: Thanks, I did do as you suggested before I posted here. I have dyslexia so sometimes I miss text even when it's right in front of me.

Comment: @DKinzer : sorry if my comment sounded violent or rude :-/

Answer (score 1):

The [JQuery documentation for each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) states:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

It also provides examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];

    jQuery.each(arr, function() {
      $("#" + this).text("Mine is " + this + ".");
       return (this != "three"); // will stop running after "three"
   });


</script>
```

Try this

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

We can not use Break and Continue in jquery functions
Try this

```
var rainbow = {'first' : 'red', 'second' : 'orange', 'third' : 'yellow'};

$.each(rainbow, function (key, color) {

  if (color == 'red') {
    //do something and then break out of the each method
    alert("i'm read, now break.");
    return false;
  }
  alert(color);
});
```