# Quit jQuery $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I break out of an $.each in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944083/how-do-i-break-out-of-an-each-in-jquery)

How to quit the jquery $.each loop?

Comment: Just read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: -1 (Explained in the API, even if slightly buried, see previous comment for link)

Comment: @pst I'd give this a -1 for being a duplicate on SO, not for being a duplicate on any other site. SO should be a place where coders can get answers to any non-duplicated questions.

Comment: cannot access the jquery doc, cos i'm living in a strange nation. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Shield_Project ^^

Comment: @pst @lovespring - which is exactly why we need to duplicate the information across the internet as much as possible.

Comment: @treeface Point taken. I have voted to close with an exact duplicate :-) @lovespring That is awful :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `return false` inside the `.each()` loop to break out entirely. Returning anything that's not false is like `continue`: it stops the current iteration and jumps right to the next.

```
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
$.each( myArr, function(){
  // Skip on three
  if( this === 3 ) return true;
  // Abort on five
  if( this === 5 ) return false;
  doStuff( this ); // never for 3, 5, 6 or 7
});
```

Answer (score 5):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

> We can break the $.each() loop at a
>   particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false.
>   Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it
>   will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Answer (score 3):

`continue` and `break` do not work the same since you are passing a callback and jQuery does the loop, but you can emulate them:

To `continue`, `return true` inside the .each callback.

To `break`, `return false`.