# jquery - how to exit (break function) from each statement?

Tags: jquery

for example I use following code:

```
$("img").each(function(i){
     x += $("img:eq(" + i ")").width();
     if(some conditional) return;
});
```

after return I would like to not adding anything to x, how could I achieve it?

Comment: return will break out of the loop as intended, what's the problem you're having?

Comment: @Ant: are you familiar with jQuery? `return` will return from the function, but only `return false;` will break the loop.

Comment: it seems like return only exit single `function(i)`

Comment: @Matt Ball - Fail on my part, too hasty with my comments! Sorry!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Break out of Jquery's Each Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquerys-each-loop)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From the [JQuery doco](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)...

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

So essentially this means...

`return false;` = `break;`

`return true;` or `return;` = `continue;`

Comment: how can i return false to  break, while also returning the value in the last loop?

Comment: @AkinHwan Try saving the value in a variable. Make sure you define the variable before the each loop and give the variable the value before returning false.

Answer (score 8):

You can `return false` to cause `each` to stop calling the function.  However, a regular loop and a break statement might be clearer.