# What has return false to do within .each() method? How can it stop the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("div").each(function (index, domEle) {
        // domEle == this
        $(domEle).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
        if($(this).is("#stop")) {
            $("span").text("Stopped at div index #" + index);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

What has `return false` to do within `.each()` method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Break out of Jquery's Each Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquerys-each-loop)

Comment: What do you expect `return false` to actually do?  If it returns from the function, the loop is going to stop, isn't it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is meant for cancelling default action and event propagation

Comment: @Maizere: When you return from the click handler.  At that point in your code, you are inside another function.

Comment: It's not working against its definition. It's working in compliance to the jQuery API.

Comment: @DaveNewton: You won't be in the *function* anymore.  Whether or not you keep looping depends on what the return value is.

Comment: @epascarello: That's not a duplicate question.

Comment: You're returning from inside the `.each`'s callback. `return`ing `false` works as `break` while returning any non-false value works as `continue`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oh, I misread the original code, never mind.

Comment: @DaveNewton: The "loop" is actually jQuery's `.each` function.  It decides whether to call the function again or not depending on the return value (and if there are elements left).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In jQuery's `.each`, `return false;` is like using `break;` in a "normal" `for` loop.

On the flip side, `return true;` is like `continue;`!

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/each/

---

`return false` does just that.  Returns `false`.  What the calling function does with the return value is a different story.  What it's "meant" to do all depends on what function is doing the `return`.  `return false` is just meant to return `false`.

If you were to return from the click handler (and not from the `.each`), then it would stop the default click action, but at that point in your code, you are inside another function.

Answer (score 5):

> *"How can it stop the loop?"*

Like this:

```
//    array        callback
each([1,2,3,4,5], function(i, val) {
    if (val === 3)
        return false;
})

function each(array, callback) {
    // iterate the collection
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        // Invoke the callback, and store its return value
        var result = callback(i, array[i]);

        // If it returned `false`, break the loop
        if (result === false) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What the value returned from a function is "meant" to do is ultimately up to the caller of that function.

In the above example, you *pass* the callback to the `each()` function, and the `each()` function calls it. Since the code in `each()` is the caller, it gets to decide what to do in response to the value returned *(if anything)*.

Answer (score 4):

> it is meant for cancelling default action and event propagation

The issue is you have 2 `function`s and are expecting `return false` to affect the "*other*" one. `return` statements apply to the *closest* `function`, which in this case is the one passed to `.each()`.

To use `return false` for the `.click()`, you'll have to use it within that `function` alone:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    // either here...

    $("div").each(function (index, domEle) {
        // ...
    });

    // ...or here
});
```

Since it appears to depend on the `.each()`, you'll want to create a variable that can be modified as needed and then return that at the end:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var clickResult; // `undefined` = "no change"

    $("div").each(function (index, domEle) {
        // domEle == this
        $(domEle).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
        if($(this).is("#stop")) {
            $("span").text("Stopped at div index #" + index);
            clickResult = false;
            return false; // remove if you want the `.each()` to continue regardless
        }
    });

    return clickResult;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` keyword does indeed break out of loops.

Cancelling a default action in JavaScript is usually done with `event.preventDefault();`, though I’m not sure which default action you’re trying to cancel in this context.

Comment: return false also cancels the event propagation

Comment: If there were an event involved

Answer (score 0):

When the callback to `.each` returns false, jQuery uses `break` to break it's internal loop. See here:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L616

this is why returning false stops the `$.each` loop from progressing.

Using `break` will have no effect due to scope, which is why the `return false` functionality was added.

Comment: The "`return false` functionality was added" because you can't use a `break;` statement in a function (outside of a looping structure).

Comment: I just wanted to clarify :-)