# Each loop to find if function exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var a = {

        b: {
            aa: 'hello',
            bb: 'you',
            cc: 'guys'
            }

    }


    var b = function(){ 

        $.each(a.b, function(x){                

            if( $.isFunction(x) == 'function' ){
                alert(x);
            };

        });

    };

    var aa = function(){
        var dude = 'hi there';
    }

    b();
```

I have an each loop inside the b function.

What i would like to do is loop through the a.b values, and find if a function exists with it's name. In this case the only one that should trigger is 'aa' as function 'aa exists.

is the isfunction line correct? or would typeof work?

Comment: var aa and the aa within your a object are two completely different values due to namespace and scope. So if you are looking to find var aa within your object you need to push it into a.b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this case the only one that should trigger is 'aa' as function 'aa exists.

`$.each()` is iterating members of the `Object` passed to it. And, currently, the `function` `aa` is not a member of the `Object` `a.b`.

`$.isFunction()` isn't returning `true` because every member of `a.b` has a `String` value:

```
aa: 'hello',
bb: 'you',
cc: 'guys'
```

If you want the `function` as a member of the `Object`, you'll need to set it as the value of one of its properties:

```
a.b.aa = function () {
    var dude = 'hi there';
};
```

This will replace the `'hello'` value with a reference to the `function`.

---

To *reuse* the property names to lookup globals, you can use them on the global object (`window` in browsers).

```
var key = 'aa';
var val = window[key];
```

```
var b = function () {
    $.each(a.b, function (key) {
        if (key in window && $.isFunction(window[key])) {
            alert(key + ' is a global function.');
        }
    });
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cAaMf/

Though, note the "**No wrap - in <body>**" in the options of the Fiddle. This will only work for globals as no other scope object can be accessed within code.

Comment: Exactly, I was thinking using push, but this would be easier since JS object are mutable.

Comment: Okay how do i 'break out' of iterating in the object passed? I want to check if a function exists in the global scope.

Comment: You can return false from the callback. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquerys-each-loop

Comment: not break the loop, i meant search the global scope instead of the object passed

Comment: @RobertHane: Just check for `"aa" in window && $.isFunction(window["aa"])`?