# Stop $.each method when desired variable found

Tags: jquery, json

I have a $.each method that searches through a JSON to find the variable and I am using this code:

```
$.each(heroes_json.heroes, function(key, val){
    if(val.id == hero){
        hero = val.localized_name;
        console.log("Hero name is "+hero);
        return;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Wrong hero, skipping...");   
    }        
});
```

The problem however is that I get this in my console log:

[image]

So from what I understand, the $.each method is, as described, going over every object in the JSON. How can it be made so that when the desired variable (in this case `hero`) is found, that it stops the each method? I am assuming that this is desired for performance purposes?

Comment: A similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquerys-each-loop

Comment: @codingstill Ah sorry. I didn't find it because I searched things like 'stop each method'. I get confused with all the names: method function loop break out etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return false from the each handler method to stop further processing of the loop

```
$.each(heroes_json.heroes, function (key, val) {
    if (val.id == hero) {
        hero = val.localized_name;
        console.log("Hero name is " + hero);
        //return false to stop the loop
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("Wrong hero, skipping...");
    }
});
```

[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You must return `false` to break out of [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
if (val.id == hero) {
    hero = val.localized_name;
    console.log("Hero name is " + hero);
    return false;
}
```

Plain `return;` is equivalent to returning `undefined`, and the `each()` loop will continue in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false in order for it to break the loop. So in your instance you will need:

```
console.log("Hero name is " + hero);
return false; //this is instead of using return;
```