# Illegal break statement in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to break a foreach if a `bool` variable is valorized:

```
 $.each(GlobalVariables.availableServices, function(index, service) 
 {
       if(state == true){  break;  }
       for (var k = 0; k < appointment.id_services.length; k++)
       {
             if(actual_option == appointment.id_services[k].id)
             {
                 serviceDuration = serviceDuration - parseInt(service['duration']);
                 state = true;
                 break;
              }
         }
 });
```

but I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

on this line:

```
if(state == true){  break;  }
```

Why happean this?

Comment: Try using `return` or `return false` instead..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1784792/1377002