# How to break out of each loop within an IF statement?

Tags: jquery

I have a function which loops through multiple table cells and checks their values against either a text box or a select box's selected value. I have an issue where if I reach a certain point in the IF statement, I would like to break out of the each loop but I'm not sure how to do this. I looked into using labels, but I don't think they work with each statements and I don't think I can use the `break;` line either.

JQuery:

```
function CheckIfPermissionExists(IsEditRole, IsPreviousPermission, DynamicElementToAdd) {
        var count = 0;
        $('.PermissionName').each(function () {
            if (IsPreviousPermission == true) {
                var PermissionNameToAdd = $('#PermissionNameSelectBox').find(":selected").val();
                if ($(this).text() == PermissionNameToAdd) {
                    $('#CreateErrorMessage').text("Please choose a different permission as this one already exists");
                    $('#CreateErrorMessage').css("display", "block");
//Break out of each here
                    return false;
                }

                else if (count < 1) {
                    AddIntoCreateTable(IsEditRole, IsPreviousPermission, DynamicElementToAdd);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else {
                var PermissionNameToAdd = $('#PermissionNameTextBox').val();
                if ($(this).text() == PermissionNameToAdd) {
                    $('#CreateErrorMessage').text("Please choose a different permission as this one already exists");
                    $('#CreateErrorMessage').css("display", "block");
                    return false;
//Break out of each here
                }
                else if (count < 1) {
                    AddIntoCreateTable(IsEditRole, IsPreviousPermission, DynamicElementToAdd);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `return false;` should act as a break inside of each function. What is your exact problem?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I don't think the break if breaking out of the each, I think it's breaking out of the IF statement

Comment: How about using `.some` from native JavaScript ? [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `break;` is something you can do in a `while (...)` or `for (...)`
>   loop, but you're inside a function. The proper way to exit a function
>   is to use `return`.
>
> If you want the `.each()` loop to stop immediately, you should `return false`.

[Source](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/breaking-the-each-loop#14737000000047339)

Comment: How come my loop continues then? I already return false

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I saved my code from the last iteration. I saved it and refreshed and it worked. My bad

Comment: @AndrewKilburn I do not know, are you sure that it enters inside the `if` condition?

Answer (score 0):

To break a $.each loop, you have to return false in the loop callback.

Returning true skips to the next iteration, equivalent to a continue in a normal loop.

[How to break out of jQuery each Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquery-each-loop)