# jQuery each - continue

Tags: jquery

while using jQuery each:

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

Is there anything like `continue` to stop the loop?

Pseudocode:

```
$.each([ 52, 97, 10, 20, 30 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
  if (value==20) {
      continue; // STOP LOOPING AND CONTINUE AT POINT (2)
  }
});
<---- POINT (2) ---->
```

Comment: Please read the documentation of `each` first. Should be the part of a research you do before asking a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of jQuery each Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquery-each-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To break `each` loop use `return false`:

```
$.each([ 52, 97, 10, 20, 30 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
  if (value==20) {
      return false;
  }
});
```

`continue` do same like `return true` and it skip immediately to the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

`$.each()` takes `return false` as a break statement:

```
$.each([ 52, 97, 10, 20, 30 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
  if (value===20) {
       return false;
  }
});

console.log("got the the rest of the script.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `return: false;`

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
  if (value == 52) { return false; }
});
```