# Each jQuery loop several several times over array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to show some data from API in my UI. I am getting an array of 12 elements, but after each loop, there are 60 items in my UI. These items are chaotic. Can I somehow break the loop, or fix this in the other way? For example, I have an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] Each loop returns 1,1,2,3,4,1,1 i.e. values are chaotic and looped several times

```
success: function (data) {
   var arr = data.Races;  // my array
   jQuery.each(arr, function (index, item) {
     var date = item.RACE_DATE;
     content += '<tr class="test-content">\n' +
                  '<td>' + date + '</td>\n +';// i am getting each item from array
                  '</tr>';
        raceInformation.append(content);
     });
  }
```

Comment: `I am getting an array of 12 elements, but after each loop, there are 60 items in my UI. These items are chaotic` Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: `'</td>\n +'` are you sure that this code is written rightly?

Comment: Yes. Question is, why "each" function looping several times

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to return false in the loop callback :

```
success: function (data) {
   var arr = data.Races;  // my array
   jQuery.each(arr, function (index, item) {
     var date = item.RACE_DATE;
     if(date===item.RACE_DATE)
     {
         content += '<tr class="test-content">\n' +
                  '<td>' + date + '</td>\n ';// i am getting each item from array
                  '</tr>';
        raceInformation.append(content);
     }
     return false;
     });
  }
```

[For more Details, Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquery-each-loop)

Comment: I have no idea what to write in the condition if. I have tried if (item === item.RACE_DATE) then return false, it doesn't working

Comment: U need to return false in else, let me modify the snippet

Comment: Try this now, I've modified

Comment: It show only first element