# How can I break out of a main function from within encapsulated .each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

***Note***: The suggested question is not exactly a duplicate, but one of the answers in there does provide a solution.

My annotated code is as follows:

```
function AddMedRow(brand, generic, dose, doseunits, freq, durn, durnunit, instrn) {
    $(".DrugRow").each(function () {
        id = $(this).attr('id');            
        count = Number(id.replace("DrugRow", ""))            
        // If this row is empty, can add here
        if ($("#brand" + count).val() == "" && $("#generic" + count).val() == "") {
            $("#brand" + count).val(brand)                
            // I actually want to return true and break out of AddMedRow
            return true
        }
    });        
    // Some other code continues here, but should not execute once the if block in .each is true
}
```

Edit: I checked with the following code:

```
function AddMedRow(brand, generic, dose, doseunits, freq, durn, durnunit, instrn) {
    dontiterate = false
    $(".DrugRow").each(function () {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log("id is " + id);
        // If this row is empty, can add here       
        count = id.replace("DrugRow", "");
        count = Number(count)
        if ($("#brand" + count).val() == "" && $("#generic" + count).val() == "") {
            $("#brand" + count).val(brand)
            dontiterate = true
            console.log("Let's see if we can break out without a control variable")
            return false
        }
    });
    if (dontiterate) {
        console.log("Not iterating because we are checking a control variable.")
        return true
    }
}
```

The result:

```
id is DrugRow1
Let's see if we can break out without a control variable
Not iterating because we are checking a control variable.
```

That means returning true or false from within .each doesnt do anything. You need to use a control variable or flag

Comment: return false instead, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquery-each-loop?rq=1

Comment: What a neat trick, thank you for this link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of jQuery each Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquery-each-loop)

Comment: @DanOswalt I dont see the false doing anything. If we set a control variable/flag and check for it outside the .each, that is doing the trick